# Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I've always handled optional parameters in JavaScript like this:

```
function myFunc(requiredArg, optionalArg){
  optionalArg = optionalArg || 'defaultValue';

  // Do stuff
}
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Are there any cases where using `||` like that is going to fail?

Comment: http://www.openjs.com/articles/optional_function_arguments.php

Comment: That's interesting.  Passing arguments as an associative array seems like a good way to handle more than a couple arguments.

Comment: That's exactly what I do in most cases. My functions with more than 1 argument expect an object literal.

Comment: @slf I believe your comment is overseen, so I added an answer about `arguments` in javascript for the googlers.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function

Comment: [Named and Optional Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) are drastically different compared to [Default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). And JavaScript doesn't support optional arguments in the same way as other languages [like c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29820290/6908282). But as mentioned already, you can pass an associative array and de-structure it in your function to handle optional arguments.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`arguments.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/length) as a workaround to achieve a [similar outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63058242/6908282).

Answer (score 1102, accepted):

Your logic fails if optionalArg is passed, but evaluates as false - try this as an alternative

```
if (typeof optionalArg === 'undefined') { optionalArg = 'default'; }
```

Or an alternative idiom:

```
optionalArg = (typeof optionalArg === 'undefined') ? 'default' : optionalArg;
```

Use whichever idiom communicates the intent best to you!

Comment: I'd user triple equals ('...lArg === "und...') to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Jarrod === is not necessary on typeof check since typeof returns a string, but no harm in doing so.

Comment: It's probably best to make using === a habit so you don't have to remember under which circumstances it's 'safe'.

Comment: Why use a ternary operator here? Isn't the 2nd clause just setting optionalArg = optionalArg?. I would think just a simple IF would do: if(typeof optionalArg === "undefined") optionalArg = "defaultValue";

Comment: Why use typeof?  

`optionalArg = (optionalArg === undefined) ? "defaultValue" : optionalArg;`

Comment: I think it signals the intent better - typeof doesn't evaluate the operate, only inspects its type, which is what we're interested in. Also, evaluation will be around 40% slower (http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow148901)

Comment: I'm finding this problematic. Using this, it did not fix the error of an unset parameter being passed into my function. I console logged the value of the unset parameter I was passing in which was getting through this protective layer, and it came out as NaN. I don't understand why this answer is so popular when that value can get through. I ended up using isNaN() for my issue.

Comment: Well, you aren't talking about optional parameters - you really *are* passing a parameter, so this solution doesn't apply to your case. NaN doesn't mean "undefined" - it means you've passing a number but its value is NaN. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215120/why-javascript-says-that-a-number-is-not-a-number for more

Comment: @PaulDixon just curious, as time goes on the benchmark results has been inverted (since Chrome 31) http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow148901 Seems like Chrome devs have optimised the more common method used

Comment: optionalAgr = optionalAgr === undefined ? defaultValue : optionalArg; IMHO typeof is redundant optionalArg is always declared in the function scope.

Comment: My implementation on a toggle: direction = (typeof direction === 'undefined') ? whatever_it_was_by_default : (direction === 'in') ? true : false;

Comment: @ShaneN I don't think it matter in js, but the ternary is useful if you always want to assign _something_ to a variable. It is somewhat easier to parallelize if there are no if() branches.

Comment: why not just `optionalArg && foo`

Comment: @SuperUberDuper - doesn't work for 'falsey' values

Comment: @PaulDixon how come?

Comment: What about the parameter positions? `function(a, b, callback)` where b is optional. If you omit `b` (`function(a, callback)`) you might find yourself comparing the value of `callback` as if it was `b`. If there is no other option, I would suggest having a single json parameter and do the checks inside: `function(myObj)`  -- then check inside for `myObj.b`, `myObj.callback`.

Comment: @noderman it is a standard in many languages that officially support optional params to have them come last. If there are more than one optional param, you can't omit the first and provide the second. If you want to provide the second, you must provide both.

Comment: The function above ( `function(a, b, callback)` ) is very common on Node.js, where `callback` is **not** optional, but `b` can be. Of course, you can write the underlying function in a way to detect if the second parameter is a function or not (if function, then it is the required callback).

Comment: optionArg = !! optionArg ?  optionArg : 'default';

Answer (score 193):

In **ECMAScript 2015** (aka "**ES6**") you can declare default argument values in the function declaration:

```
function myFunc(requiredArg, optionalArg = 'defaultValue') {
    // do stuff
}
```

More about them in [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters).

This is currently [only supported by Firefox](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-default_function_parameters), but as the standard has been completed, expect support to improve rapidly.

---

**EDIT (2019-06-12):**

Default parameters are now widely supported by modern browsers.
All versions of Internet **Explorer** do not support this feature. However, **Chrome**, **Firefox**, and **Edge** currently support it.

Comment: This is proof enough to me, that JavaScript is indeed evil. @ThoAppelsin

Comment: JavaScript is only evil to those who don't understand it (not saying you don't, but that's my opinion). I think it's paradigm is really powerful in concept (implementations are consistently getting better).

Comment: Oh, hello Python syntax. Nice to see you again.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak And C# syntax (for default values, if nothing else).

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak same goes for many other languages not just Python or C# :) It is rather common approach for default argument values.

Comment: As ES6 is current standard, this is proper answer.

Answer (score 126):

I find this to be the simplest, most readable way:

```
if (typeof myVariable === 'undefined') { myVariable = 'default'; }
//use myVariable here
```

Paul Dixon's answer (in my humble opinion) is less readable than this, but it comes down to preference.

insin's answer is much more advanced, but much more useful for big functions!

**EDIT 11/17/2013 9:33pm:** I've created a package for Node.js that makes it easier to "overload" functions (methods) called [parametric](https://npmjs.org/package/parametric).

Comment: I made this answer, and the accepted answer, fight to the death. The accepter answer's ternary method was slightly slower for the handful of tests I ran: http://jsperf.com/optional-function-parameters-ternary-vs-manual

Answer (score 45):

If you need to chuck a literal `NULL` in, then you could have some issues. Apart from that, no, I think you're probably on the right track.

The other method some people choose is taking an assoc array of variables iterating through the argument list. It looks a bit neater but I imagine it's a little (very little) bit more process/memory intensive.

```
function myFunction (argArray) {
    var defaults = {
        'arg1'  :   "value 1",
        'arg2'  :   "value 2",
        'arg3'  :   "value 3",
        'arg4'  :   "value 4"
    }

    for(var i in defaults) 
        if(typeof argArray[i] == "undefined") 
               argArray[i] = defaults[i];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: why not hasOwnProperty instead of == "undefined" ?

Comment: Why not `if (!(i in argArray))` instead? And for completeness, before this `if`-statement, there should be a check for the correct argument type, e.g. `if (typeof argArray !== "object") argArray = [];`.

Answer (score 33):

Ideally, you would refactor to pass an object and [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/?answertab=votes) it with a default object, so the order in which arguments are passed doesn't matter (see the second section of this answer, below).

If, however, you just want something quick, reliable, easy to use and not bulky, try this:

---

### A clean quick fix for any number of default arguments

- It scales elegantly: minimal extra code for each new default
- You can paste it anywhere: just change the number of required args and variables
- If you want to pass `undefined` to an argument with a default value, this way, the variable is set as `undefined`. Most other options on this page would replace `undefined` with the default value.

Here's an example for providing defaults for three optional arguments (with two required  arguments)

```
function myFunc( requiredA, requiredB,  optionalA, optionalB, optionalC ) {

  switch (arguments.length - 2) { // 2 is the number of required arguments
    case 0:  optionalA = 'Some default';
    case 1:  optionalB = 'Another default';
    case 2:  optionalC = 'Some other default';
    // no breaks between cases: each case implies the next cases are also needed
  }

}
```

[**Simple demo**](http://jsbin.com/pecorogevi/1/edit). This is similar to [roenving's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148933/568458), but easily extendible for any number of default arguments, easier to update, and [using `arguments` not `Function.arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

---

### Passing and merging objects for more flexibility

The above code, like many ways of doing default arguments, can't pass arguments out of sequence, e.g., passing `optionalC` but leaving `optionalB` to fall back to its default.

A good option for that is to pass objects and merge with a default object. This is also good for maintainability (just take care to keep your code readable, so future collaborators won't be left guessing about the possible contents of the objects you pass around).

Example using jQuery. If you don't use jQuery, you could instead use Underscore's `_.defaults(object, defaults)` or [browse these options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/?answertab=votes):

```
function myFunc( args ) {
  var defaults = {
    optionalA: 'Some default',
    optionalB: 'Another default',
    optionalC: 'Some other default'
  };
  args = $.extend({}, defaults, args);
}
```

Here's [a simple example of it in action](http://jsbin.com/yahuqocira/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Not sure I understand this one. Wouldn't it also replace the value when the parameter is actually given?! Oo

Comment: Hey,  this is about the cleanest way I have seen.  The only problem with it is this: http://jsperf.com/optional-parameters-typeof-vs-switch     The switch is apparently very slow..

Comment: Not sure I'd call 23.6 million operations per second slow... it's true that `typeof` is incredibly fast, but that doesn't make `switch` slow - just not as incredibly fast.

Answer (score 19):

You can use some different schemes for that. I've always tested for arguments.length:

```
function myFunc(requiredArg, optionalArg){
  optionalArg = myFunc.arguments.length<2 ? 'defaultValue' : optionalArg;

  ...
```

-- doing so, it can't possibly fail, but I don't know if your way has any chance of failing, just now I can't think up a scenario, where it actually would fail ...

And then Paul provided one failing scenario !-)

Comment: I am surprised no one has mentioned using the arguments array!

Comment: What is the "one failing scenario"? If you pass false, null, 0, etc, that doesn't change the length of the arguments array. Otherwise, using this with switch(myFunc.arguments.length) is good and flexible.

Comment: Oh, I see - you meant one failing scenario in the OP, not one failing scenario with your solution.

Answer (score 14):

Similar to Oli's answer, I use an argument Object and an Object which defines the default values. With a little bit of sugar...

```
/**
 * Updates an object's properties with other objects' properties. All
 * additional non-falsy arguments will have their properties copied to the
 * destination object, in the order given.
 */
function extend(dest) {
  for (var i = 1, l = arguments.length; i < l; i++) {
    var src = arguments[i]
    if (!src) {
      continue
    }
    for (var property in src) {
      if (src.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        dest[property] = src[property]
      }
    }
  }
  return dest
}

/**
 * Inherit another function's prototype without invoking the function.
 */
function inherits(child, parent) {
  var F = function() {}
  F.prototype = parent.prototype
  child.prototype = new F()
  child.prototype.constructor = child
  return child
}
```

...this can be made a bit nicer.

```
function Field(kwargs) {
  kwargs = extend({
    required: true, widget: null, label: null, initial: null,
    helpText: null, errorMessages: null
  }, kwargs)
  this.required = kwargs.required
  this.label = kwargs.label
  this.initial = kwargs.initial
  // ...and so on...
}

function CharField(kwargs) {
  kwargs = extend({
    maxLength: null, minLength: null
  }, kwargs)
  this.maxLength = kwargs.maxLength
  this.minLength = kwargs.minLength
  Field.call(this, kwargs)
}
inherits(CharField, Field)
```

What's nice about this method?

- You can omit as many arguments as you like - if you only want to override the value of one argument, you can just provide that argument, instead of having to explicitly pass `undefined` when, say there are 5 arguments and you only want to customise the last one, as you would have to do with some of the other methods suggested.
- When working with a constructor Function for an object which inherits from another, it's easy to accept any arguments which are required by the constructor of the Object you're inheriting from, as you don't have to name those arguments in your constructor signature, or even provide your own defaults (let the parent Object's constructor do that for you, as seen above when `CharField` calls `Field`'s constructor).
- Child objects in inheritance hierarchies can customise arguments for their parent constructor as they see fit, enforcing their own default values or ensuring that a certain value will *always* be used.

Comment: i hate from complex functions and them long documents.

Answer (score 9):

***Loose type checking***

Easy to write, but `0`, `''`, `false`, `null` and `undefined` will be converted to default value, which might not be expected outcome.

```
function myFunc(requiredArg, optionalArg) {
    optionalArg = optionalArg || 'defaultValue';
}
```

***Strict type checking***

Longer, but covers majority of cases. Only case where it incorrectly assigns default value is when we pass `undefined` as parameter.

```
function myFunc(requiredArg, optionalArg) {
    optionalArg = typeof optionalArg !== 'undefined' ? optionalArg : 'defaultValue';
}
```

***Checking arguments variable***

Catches all cases but is the most clumsy to write.

```
function myFunc(requiredArg, optionalArg1, optionalArg2) {
    optionalArg1 = arguments.length > 1 ? optionalArg1 : 'defaultValue';
    optionalArg2 = arguments.length > 2 ? optionalArg2 : 'defaultValue';
}
```

***ES6***

Unfortunately this has very poor browser support at the moment

```
function myFunc(requiredArg, optionalArg = 'defaultValue') {

}
```

Comment: *"Checking arguments variable - Catches all cases but is the most clumsy to write"* And in loose mode can have negative performance implications thanks to using `arguments` (not that it usually matters).

Answer (score 8):

If you're using defaults extensively, this seems much more readable:

```
function usageExemple(a,b,c,d){
    //defaults
    a=defaultValue(a,1);
    b=defaultValue(b,2);
    c=defaultValue(c,4);
    d=defaultValue(d,8);

    var x = a+b+c+d;
    return x;
}
```

Just declare this function on the global escope.

```
function defaultValue(variable,defaultValue){
    return(typeof variable!=='undefined')?(variable):(defaultValue);
}
```

Usage pattern `fruit = defaultValue(fruit,'Apple');`

*PS you can rename the `defaultValue` function to a short name, just don't use `default` it's a reserved word in javascript.

Comment: +1 because I was going to post my solution which is just the same:  `function defaultFor(arg, val) { return typeof arg !== 'undefined' ? arg : val; }`

Answer (score 6):

I am used to seeing a few basic variations on handling optional variables. Sometimes, the relaxed versions are useful.

```
function foo(a, b, c) {
  a = a || "default";   // Matches 0, "", null, undefined, NaN, false.
  a || (a = "default"); // Matches 0, "", null, undefined, NaN, false.

  if (b == null) { b = "default"; } // Matches null, undefined.

  if (typeof c === "undefined") { c = "default"; } // Matches undefined.
}
```

The falsy default used with variable `a` is, for example, used extensively in [Backbone.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backbone.js).

Answer (score 6):

With ES2015/ES6 you can take advantage of `Object.assign` which can replace `$.extend()` or `_.defaults()`

```
function myFunc(requiredArg, options = {}) {
  const defaults = {
    message: 'Hello',
    color: 'red',
    importance: 1
  };

  const settings = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);

  // do stuff
}
```

You can also use defaults arguments like this

```
function myFunc(requiredArg, { message: 'Hello', color: 'red', importance: 1 } = {}) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: In future, you will be able to write this even shorter with object spreading (currently NOT supported by Edge!) - demonstration fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L7evm21q/ basic code: `function test(options) {
    options = {
       someDefaultParam: '',
       ...options
    };

    /* do stuff */
}`
future ref link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) library (you should, it's an awesome library):

```
_.defaults(optionalArg, 'defaultValue');
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why @Paul's reply is downvoted, but the validation against `null` is a good choice. Maybe a more affirmative example will make better sense:

In JavaScript a missed parameter is like a declared variable that is not initialized (just `var a1;`). And the equality operator converts the undefined to null, so this works great with both value types and objects, and this is how CoffeeScript handles optional parameters.

```
function overLoad(p1){
    alert(p1 == null); // Caution, don't use the strict comparison: === won't work.
    alert(typeof p1 === 'undefined');
}

overLoad(); // true, true
overLoad(undefined); // true, true. Yes, undefined is treated as null for equality operator.
overLoad(10); // false, false


function overLoad(p1){
    if (p1 == null) p1 = 'default value goes here...';
    //...
}
```

Though, there are concerns that for the best semantics is `typeof variable === 'undefined'` is slightly better. I'm not about to defend this since it's the matter of the underlying API how a function is implemented; it should not interest the API user.

I should also add that here's the only way to physically make sure any argument were missed, using the `in` operator which unfortunately won't work with the parameter names so have to pass an index of the `arguments`.

```
function foo(a, b) {
    // Both a and b will evaluate to undefined when used in an expression
    alert(a); // undefined
    alert(b); // undefined

    alert("0" in arguments); // true
    alert("1" in arguments); // false
}

foo (undefined);
```

Answer (score 2):

The test for undefined is unnecessary and isn't as robust as it could be because, as user568458 pointed out, the solution provided fails if null or false is passed. Users of your API might think false or null would force the method to avoid that parameter.

```
function PaulDixonSolution(required, optionalArg){
   optionalArg = (typeof optionalArg === "undefined") ? "defaultValue" : optionalArg;
   console.log(optionalArg);
};
PaulDixonSolution("required");
PaulDixonSolution("required", "provided");
PaulDixonSolution("required", null);
PaulDixonSolution("required", false);
```

The result is:

```
defaultValue
provided
null
false
```

Those last two are potentially bad. Instead try:

```
function bulletproof(required, optionalArg){
   optionalArg = optionalArg ? optionalArg : "defaultValue";;
   console.log(optionalArg);
};
bulletproof("required");
bulletproof("required", "provided");
bulletproof("required", null);
bulletproof("required", false);
```

Which results in:

```
defaultValue
provided
defaultValue
defaultValue
```

The only scenario where this isn't optimal is when you actually have optional parameters that are meant to be booleans or intentional null.

Answer (score 2):

I tried some options mentioned in here and performance tested them. At this moment the logicalor seems to be the fastest. Although this is subject of change over time (different JavaScript engine versions).

These are my results (Microsoft Edge 20.10240.16384.0):

```
Function executed            Operations/sec     Statistics
TypeofFunction('test');          92,169,505     ±1.55%   9% slower
SwitchFuntion('test');            2,904,685     ±2.91%  97% slower
ObjectFunction({param1: 'test'});   924,753     ±1.71%  99% slower
LogicalOrFunction('test');      101,205,173     ±0.92%     fastest
TypeofFunction2('test');         35,636,836     ±0.59%  65% slower
```

This performance test can be easily replicated on:
http://jsperf.com/optional-parameters-typeof-vs-switch/2

This is the code of the test:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Benchmark.prototype.setup = function() {
        function TypeofFunction(param1, optParam1, optParam2, optParam3) {
            optParam1 = (typeof optParam1 === "undefined") ? "Some default" : optParam1;
            optParam2 = (typeof optParam2 === "undefined") ? "Another default" : optParam2;
            optParam3 = (typeof optParam3 === "undefined") ? "Some other default" : optParam3;
        }

        function TypeofFunction2(param1, optParam1, optParam2, optParam3) {
            optParam1 = defaultValue(optParam1, "Some default");
            optParam2 = defaultValue(optParam2, "Another default");
            optParam3 = defaultValue(optParam3, "Some other default");
        }

        function defaultValue(variable, defaultValue) {
            return (typeof variable !== 'undefined') ? (variable) : (defaultValue);
        }

        function SwitchFuntion(param1, optParam1, optParam2, optParam3) {
            switch (arguments.length - 1) { // <-- 1 is number of required arguments
                case 0:
                    optParam1 = 'Some default';
                case 1:
                    optParam2 = 'Another default';
                case 2:
                    optParam3 = 'Some other default';
            }
        }

        function ObjectFunction(args) {
            var defaults = {
                optParam1: 'Some default',
                optParam2: 'Another default',
                optParam3: 'Some other default'
            }
            args = $.extend({}, defaults, args);
        }

        function LogicalOrFunction(param1, optParam1, optParam2, optParam3) {
            optParam1 || (optParam1 = 'Some default');
            optParam2 || (optParam1 = 'Another default');
            optParam3 || (optParam1 = 'Some other default');
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Landed to this question, searching for **default parameters in EcmaScript 2015**, thus just mentioning...

With **ES6** we can do [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters):

```
function doSomething(optionalParam = "defaultValue"){
    console.log(optionalParam);//not required to check for falsy values
}

doSomething(); //"defaultValue"
doSomething("myvalue"); //"myvalue"
```

Answer (score 2):

During a project I noticed I was repeating myself too much with the optional parameters and settings, so I made a class that handles the type checking and assigns a default value which results in neat and readable code. See example and let me know if this works for you.

```
var myCar           = new Car('VW', {gearbox:'automatic', options:['radio', 'airbags 2x']});
var myOtherCar      = new Car('Toyota');

function Car(brand, settings) {
    this.brand      = brand;

    // readable and adjustable code
    settings        = DefaultValue.object(settings, {});
    this.wheels     = DefaultValue.number(settings.wheels, 4);
    this.hasBreaks  = DefaultValue.bool(settings.hasBreaks, true);
    this.gearbox    = DefaultValue.string(settings.gearbox, 'manual');
    this.options    = DefaultValue.array(settings.options, []);

    // instead of doing this the hard way
    settings        = settings || {};
    this.wheels     = (!isNaN(settings.wheels)) ? settings.wheels : 4;
    this.hasBreaks  = (typeof settings.hasBreaks !== 'undefined') ? (settings.hasBreaks === true) : true;
    this.gearbox    = (typeof settings.gearbox === 'string') ? settings.gearbox : 'manual';
    this.options    = (typeof settings.options !== 'undefined' && Array.isArray(settings.options)) ? settings.options : [];
}
```

Using this class:

```
(function(ns) {

    var DefaultValue = {

        object: function(input, defaultValue) {
            if (typeof defaultValue !== 'object') throw new Error('invalid defaultValue type');
            return (typeof input !== 'undefined') ? input : defaultValue;
        },

        bool: function(input, defaultValue) {
            if (typeof defaultValue !== 'boolean') throw new Error('invalid defaultValue type');
            return (typeof input !== 'undefined') ? (input === true) : defaultValue;
        },

        number: function(input, defaultValue) {
            if (isNaN(defaultValue)) throw new Error('invalid defaultValue type');
            return (typeof input !== 'undefined' && !isNaN(input)) ? parseFloat(input) : defaultValue;
        },

        // wrap the input in an array if it is not undefined and not an array, for your convenience
        array: function(input, defaultValue) {
            if (typeof defaultValue === 'undefined') throw new Error('invalid defaultValue type');
            return (typeof input !== 'undefined') ? (Array.isArray(input) ? input : [input]) : defaultValue;
        },

        string: function(input, defaultValue) {
            if (typeof defaultValue !== 'string') throw new Error('invalid defaultValue type');
            return (typeof input === 'string') ? input : defaultValue;
        },

    };

    ns.DefaultValue = DefaultValue;

}(this));
```

Comment: I like that and I'll go similar way. (My only parameter is and object with up to 20 props were maybe 7 are very important). Actually its not only redable and maintainable, it is also reusable and extendable (f.e. adding callback/emit something). Its very clear, thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with:

```
function WhoLikesCake(options) {
  options = options || {};
  var defaultOptions = {
    a : options.a || "Huh?",
    b : options.b || "I don't like cake."
  }
  console.log('a: ' + defaultOptions.b + ' - b: ' + defaultOptions.b);

  // Do more stuff here ...
}
```

Called like this:

```
WhoLikesCake({ b : "I do" });
```

Comment: `WhoLikesCake({a: false})` boom your function doesn't work anymore ;)

Answer (score 1):

Folks -

After looking at these and other solutions, I tried a number of them out using a snippet of code originally from W3Schools as a base.  You can find what works in the following.  Each of the items commented out work as well and are that way to allow you to experiment simply by removing individual comments.  To be clear, it is the "eyecolor" parameter that is not being defined.

```
function person(firstname, lastname, age, eyecolor)
{
this.firstname = firstname;
this.lastname = lastname;
this.age = age;
this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
// if(null==eyecolor)
//   this.eyecolor = "unknown1";
//if(typeof(eyecolor)==='undefined') 
//   this.eyecolor = "unknown2";
// if(!eyecolor)
//   this.eyecolor = "unknown3";
this.eyecolor = this.eyecolor || "unknown4";
}

var myFather = new person("John", "Doe", 60);
var myMother = new person("Sally", "Rally", 48, "green");

var elem = document.getElementById("demo");
elem.innerHTML = "My father " +
              myFather.firstname + " " +
              myFather.lastname + " is " +
              myFather.age + " with " +
              myFather.eyecolor + " eyes.<br/>" +
              "My mother " +
              myMother.firstname + " " +
              myMother.lastname + " is " +
              myMother.age + " with " +
              myMother.eyecolor + " eyes.";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Default(variable, new_value)
{
    if(new_value === undefined) { return (variable === undefined) ? null : variable; }
    return (variable === undefined) ? new_value : variable;
}

var a = 2, b = "hello", c = true, d;

var test = Default(a, 0),
test2 = Default(b, "Hi"),
test3 = Default(c, false),
test4 = Default(d, "Hello world");

window.alert(test + "\n" + test2 + "\n" + test3 + "\n" + test4);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mq60hqrf/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. With this  you can leave any parameter you want. The order of the optional parameters is not important and you can add custom validation.

```
function YourFunction(optionalArguments) {
            //var scope = this;

            //set the defaults
            var _value1 = 'defaultValue1';
            var _value2 = 'defaultValue2';
            var _value3 = null;
            var _value4 = false;

            //check the optional arguments if they are set to override defaults...
            if (typeof optionalArguments !== 'undefined') {

                if (typeof optionalArguments.param1 !== 'undefined')
                    _value1 = optionalArguments.param1;

                if (typeof optionalArguments.param2 !== 'undefined')
                    _value2 = optionalArguments.param2;

                if (typeof optionalArguments.param3 !== 'undefined')
                    _value3 = optionalArguments.param3;

                if (typeof optionalArguments.param4 !== 'undefined')
                    //use custom parameter validation if needed, in this case for javascript boolean
                   _value4 = (optionalArguments.param4 === true || optionalArguments.param4 === 'true');
            }

            console.log('value summary of function call:');
            console.log('value1: ' + _value1);
            console.log('value2: ' + _value2);
            console.log('value3: ' + _value3);
            console.log('value4: ' + _value4);
            console.log('');
        }


        //call your function in any way you want. You can leave parameters. Order is not important. Here some examples:
        YourFunction({
            param1: 'yourGivenValue1',
            param2: 'yourGivenValue2',
            param3: 'yourGivenValue3',
            param4: true,
        });

        //order is not important
        YourFunction({
            param4: false,
            param1: 'yourGivenValue1',
            param2: 'yourGivenValue2',
        });

        //uses all default values
        YourFunction();

        //keeps value4 false, because not a valid value is given
        YourFunction({
            param4: 'not a valid bool'
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `arg || 'default'` is a great way and works for 90% of cases
2. It fails when you need to pass values that might be 'falsy'

   - `false`
   - `0`
   - `NaN`
   - `""`

   For these cases you will need to be a bit more verbose and check for `undefined`
3. Also be careful when you have optional arguments first, you have to be aware of the types of all of your arguments

Answer (score 1):

In all cases where optionalArg is falsy you will end up with defaultValue.

```
function myFunc(requiredArg, optionalArg) {
    optionalArg = optionalArg || 'defaultValue';
    console.log(optionalArg);
    // Do stuff
}
myFunc(requiredArg);
myFunc(requiredArg, null);
myFunc(requiredArg, undefined);
myFunc(requiredArg, "");
myFunc(requiredArg, 0);
myFunc(requiredArg, false);
```

All of the above log defaultValue, because all of 6 are falsy. In case 4, 5, 6 you might not be interested to set optionalArg as defaultValue, but it sets since they are falsy.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems like the simplest way (for one argument, anyway):

```
function myFunction(Required,Optional)
{
    if (arguments.length<2) Optional = "Default";
    //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those ones are shorter than the typeof operator version.

```
function foo(a, b) {
    a !== undefined || (a = 'defaultA');
    if(b === undefined) b = 'defaultB';
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the safest way - to deal with all \ any ***falsy types*** of supplied *arguments* before deciding to use the ***default*** - is to check for the existence\presence of the *optional argument* in the invoked function.

Relying on the arguments object member creation which doesn't even get created if the argument is missing, regardless of the fact that it might be declared, we can write your function like this:

```
  function myFunc(requiredArg, optionalArg){
        optionalArg = 1 in arguments ? optionalArg : 'defaultValue';
  //do stuff
  }
```

Utilizing this behavior: 
We can safely check for any missing values on arguments list arbitrarily and explicitly whenever we need to make sure the function gets a certain value required in its procedure.

In the following demo code we will deliberately put a *typeless* and *valueless* ***undefined*** as a default value to be able to determine whether it might fail on falsy argument values, such as 0 false etc., or if it behaves as expected.

```
function argCheck( arg1, arg2, arg3 ){

       arg1 = 0 in arguments || undefined;
       arg2 = 1 in arguments || false;
       arg3 = 2 in arguments || 0;
   var arg4 = 3 in arguments || null;

   console.log( arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4 ) 
}
```

Now, checking few falsy argument-values to see if their presence is correctly detected and therefore evaluates to ***true***:

```
argCheck( "", 0, false, null );
>> true true true true
```

Which means -they didn't fail the recognition of/as expected argument values.
Here we have a check with all arguments missing, which according to our algo should acquire their default values even if they're *falsy*.

```
argCheck( );
>> undefined false 0 null
```

As we can see, the arguments *arg1, arg2, arg3* and the undeclared *arg4*, are returning their exact ***default*** values, as ordered. 
Because we've now made sure that it works, we can rewrite the function which will actually be able to use them as in the first example by using: either ***if*** or a *ternary* condition.

On functions that have more than one optional argument, - a loop through, might have saved us some bits. But since argument ***names*** don't get initialized if their values are not supplied, we cannot access them by names anymore even if we've programmatically written a default value, we can only access them by *arguments[index]* which useless code readability wise.

But aside from this inconvenience, which in certain coding situations might be fully acceptable, there's another unaccounted problem for multiple and arbitrary number of argument defaults. Which may and should be considered a bug, as we can no longer skip arguments, as we once might have been able to, without giving a value, in a syntax such as:

```
argCheck("a",,22,{});
```

because it will throw! Which makes it impossible for us to substitute our argument with a specific *falsy* type of our desired default value.
Which is stupid, since the *arguments object* is an array-like object and is expected to support this syntax and convention as is, natively or by default!

Because of this shortsighted decision we can no longer hope to write a function like this:

```
function argCheck( ) {
    var _default = [undefined, 0, false, null ],
        _arg = arguments;

 for( var x in _default ) {
         x in _arg ? 1 : _arg[x] = _default[x];
        }
    console.log( _arg[0],_arg[1],_arg[2],_arg[3] );
}
```

in which case, we would be able to write each default value of a desired type in arguments row and be able to at least access them by args.index.

For instance this function call would yield:

```
argCheck();
>>undefined 0 false null
```

as defined in our default array of arguments values.
However the following is still possible:

```
argCheck({})
>>Object {  } 0 false null

argCheck({}, [])
>>Object {  } Array [  ] false null
```

But regretfully not:

```
 argCheck("a",,,22);
 >>SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','
```

Which would otherwise be logging:

```
>>a 0 false 22
```

but that's in a better world!
However - for the original question - the topmost function will do just fine.
e.g.:

```
function argCheck( arg, opt ) {
         1 in arguments ? 1 : opt = "default";
         console.log( arg, opt );
}
```

p.s.: sorry for not preserving the *types* of chosen defaults in my argument inputs while writing them.

Comment: A JavaScript illiterate has just down-voted the best and the most complete answer on the issue without even knowing why. Maybe because it is to elaborate and got lost in the process. Better luck next time, with your reading and comprehension abilities. :)

Comment: There's many reasons to downvote and no one owes you an explanation as to why they did so. Don't take it too personal, it's non-constructive and a bad look

Comment: The main reason out of "many reasons" - in this case - is being a radical JavaScript ignorant - As about your unapparent false remark that no one owes an explanation for an occasionally 'stupid' downvote, is incorrect - because as far as I remember from the first time I felt I had to downvote, the SO policy required / instructed me to also give an explanation for the downvote.

Comment: Misusing big words doesn't take away the fact that in more than one of your other answers you get the exact same response as I gave you. You might be better off taking it as constructive criticism the next time around. If everyone looks ignorant but you, perhaps it is you who might be the ignorant.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides where is that constructive criticism because there is none. Downvote is not a criticism - it is a punishment without explanation and it may be simply because of the color of my skin.

Comment: `it may be simply because of the color of my skin` - I can almost guarantee you the community is not like that at all. Be nicer when asking for comments on down votes and someone will give it to you is all I'm saying.

Comment: The community is not like that, but it is made out of individuals who never knew each other. -I was being very nice, and yet - everybody knows that Greeks hate Albanians. :) You'll have to point to my error for an honest and constructive downvote that everybody would benefit from. Otherwise, downvoting a qualitative answer, is a malicious act and against the community interests.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use [ArgueJS](https://github.com/zvictor/ArgueJs) this way:

```
function myFunc(){
  arguments = __({requiredArg: undefined, optionalArg: [undefined: 'defaultValue'})

  //do stuff, using arguments.requiredArg and arguments.optionalArg
  //    to access your arguments

}
```

You can also replace `undefined` by the type of the argument you expect to receive, like this:

```
function myFunc(){
  arguments = __({requiredArg: Number, optionalArg: [String: 'defaultValue'})

  //do stuff, using arguments.requiredArg and arguments.optionalArg
  //    to access your arguments

}
```

Comment: No longer maintained.

Answer (score -2):

```
function foo(requiredArg){
  if(arguments.length>1) var optionalArg = arguments[1];
}
```

Comment: You might want to fix that typo and add an explanation for what you're recommending here.

Comment: I don't think this needs much explanation, it simply answers the question. There are many ways of accomplishing "optional function parameters" in JavaScript. I have seen 3 or 4 other good answers here, but I have not seen this answer given, so I gave it. It may not be the simplest or most straightforward answer but it does work.

Comment: This is the same as Roenving's answer, but doesn't provide a default value. That said, I quite like the readability of defining optional args separately to required ones: if that's the purpose of your answer, it'd help to say so

Comment: I do not think my answer is by any means the best. I rather prefer angelcool.net's answer. I was simply listing that this is another option. I would never use this method, I just thought the asker would prefer to have all available options proposed and they can choose for themselves which method they like best, and I noticed this answer was not given, and so in order to try and provide the asker with the most complete answer I felt this option (though it sucks) should be given.