# Overloading methods in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, overloading

Is there a way to simplify the process of adding an overloaded method in C# using VS2005?

In VB6, I would have just added an Optional parameter the function, but in C# do I have to have to type out a whole new method with this new parameter?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199761/how-can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-c - fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with c# 2.0 there is only a way with code generation tools. resharper could do this. with c# 4.0 optional parameters are possible too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In C# 4.0 you can use optional parameters, but in C# 2.0 you have to specify them manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with .net 4.0:

```
   1:  public void SendMail(string toAddress, string bodyText, bool ccAdministrator = true, bool isBodyHtml = false)
   2:  {
   3:      // Full implementation here
   4:  }
```

In earlier version you need to write separate methods.

Answer (score 0):

C# 4.0 has optional parameters - see the [programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).