# Default method parameters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, optional-parameters

How can I make a method have default values for parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you use optional parameters in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199761/how-can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to overload the method:

```
private void Foo(int length)
{
}

private void Foo()
{
    Foo(20);
}
```

Comment: This is still a good solution, even in C# 4.  One advantage of this is that the default values are embedded in your assembly rather than the callers'; see Jon's answer for more details.

Comment: @Dan: I've become increasingly skeptical about the *real* damage of the "you can't change default values" issue... because for most code, I expect that the whole app will be recompiled anyway. It's something worth knowing about, but I don't think it's really a huge issue.

Comment: @Jon, I'm inclined to agree with you, as I think it would probably be bad practice to rely on particular default values, in any case, as that would seem to indicate that the nature of the API has changed.  If that's the case, the client probably needs to change anyway.

Answer (score 16):

You can only do this in C# 4, which introduced both [named arguments and optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

```
public void Foo(int x = 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

...
Foo(); // Prints 10
```

Note that the default value has to be a constant - either a normal compile-time constant (e.g. a literal) or:

- The parameterless constructor of a value type
- `default(T)` for some type `T`

Also note that the default value is embedded in the *caller's* assembly (assuming you omit the relevant argument) - so if you change the default value without rebuilding the calling code, you'll still see the old value.

This (and other new features in C# 4) are covered in the second edition of [C# in Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet3). (Chapter 13 in this case.)

Comment: Link to the `C# in Depth` book is wrong.

The `manning.com` website returns a PHP file which redirects to a website which cannot be loaded.

Comment: @NikolayKostov: Humbug - affliate program changed a while ago. I've included a simpler link here.

Answer (score 12):

C# 4.0 allows you to use [named and optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

```
public void ExampleMethod(
    int required, 
    string optionalstr = "default string",
    int optionalint = 10
)
```

In previous versions you could [simulate default parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287762(VS.71).aspx) by using method overloading.

Answer (score 8):

You simply declare them with the default values - they are called [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

```
 public void myMethod(string param1 = "default", int param2 = 3)
 {
 }
```

This was introduced in C# 4.0 (so you will need to use visual studio 2010).