# How can we declare Optional Parameters in C#.net?

Tags: c#, option-type

I am using a method for doing some action, i want the method to be written only once by using Optional Parameters in C#, other than Method Overloading is there any?

Comment: there may be a lot of issues which can occur if you are changing the signature of a function without overloading.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914858/can-i-give-default-value-to-parameters-in-c-sharp-functions

Answer (score 39, accepted):

New to visual studio 2010

[named and optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

for example

```
public void ExampleMethod(int required, string optionalstr = "default string",
int optionalint = 10)
{
}
```

Comment: Did you just copy-paste Oded's answer for this?

Comment: FWIW, no he didn't. If you read the link he provided, it's the example given by MSDN.

Answer (score 15):

Have a look at following code

Library to use

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Function declaration

```
private void SampleFunction([Optional]string optionalVar, string strVar)
{
}
```

And while giving call to function you can do like this

```
SampleFunction(optionalVar: "someValue","otherValue");
```

OR

```
SampleFunction("otherValue");
```

Reply if it helps.!:)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, use [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) (introduced in C# 4).

```
public void ExampleMethod(int required, string optionalstr = "default string",
    int optionalint = 10)
```

When you provide a default value to a formal parameter, it becomes optional.

For prior versions, overloads are the only option.

Answer (score 4):

They have been introduced in C# 2010 (that is *generally* VS2010 with Framework 4.0). See [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

In previous C# versions you're stuck with overloads (or param arrays).

Comment: Ya, the answer given by @Reddog matches with my recent search in MSDN. And the thing worked me out, when i updated my version.

Answer (score 2):

If you use **C# 4.0** it is.

You can then define your method like this:

```
public void Foo( int a = 3, int b = 5 ){
  //at this point, if the method was called without parameters, a will be 3 and b will be 5.
}
```

Comment: You don't have to be using .NET 4. You just have to be using the C# 4 compiler. You can be *targeting* .NET 2.

Comment: @Øyvind: Duly removed my downvote :)