# Default Value in a C# Function

Tags: c#

is it possible to do this in C#? (in C++ its not)

```
function sum ( int a = 9, int b = 4){

}
```

and then call the function like :

```
int someValue = sum(, 14) // so 14 is for the second value
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I give default value to parameters or optional parameters in C# functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914858/can-i-give-default-value-to-parameters-or-optional-parameters-in-c-sharp-functio)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

C# 4 allows named arguments and optional parameters<sup>1</sup>:

```
int Sum (int a = 9, int b = 4)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Then:

```
Sum(10, 5);       // Positional arguments as "normal"
Sum(b: 5);        // Use the default value for a
Sum(a: 5);        // Use the default value for b
Sum();            // Default both parameters
Sum(b: 1, a: 10); // Arguments can be reordered
```

EDIT: For overloaded methods, if there are multiple matches the compiler checks whether any of those candidates are only valid due to giving default values. If that's the case, those candidates are effectively given priority. This is one of the tie-breaking rules listed in section 7.5.3.2. There's no preference for just using "fewer" default values; it's an all or nothing approach. I give an example of this in my [article on overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx).

---

<sup>1</sup> It's unfortunate that the terminology is often confused, even by Microsoft. Parameters have always have names - what's new is that you can specify the name in the *calling* code, for the argument. On the other hand, you make the *parameter* optional by specifying a default.

Comment: Jon if you can shed more light on how it will behave if there are overloaded methods please :). How does compiler/runtime knows should it bother with finding overloaded methods or not

Comment: @SSamra i think you might be looking for [this series on optional arguments](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/09/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-one.aspx)

Comment: @SSamra: Have added a section on this.

Comment: Thanks Jon,hard to say if i am more confident about optional parameters or not, just scares me "no of overloading methods in number of interfaces exposed through WCF in a heavy duty Finance Back Office I am working with" if a new developer joins the team and start using optional parameters.

Comment: @SSamra: Certainly optional parameters need to be used with caution, and overloading methods with optional parameters is likely to introduce more confusion... I'd be tempted not to mix the two.

Answer (score 5):

With C# 4 you can do `int someValue = sum (b: 14);`

EDIT - as per comments:

C++ can have default values for parameters... these parameters can be "skipped" when calling a method/function BUT the rule in C++ is that only the right-most parameters can be skipped... which makes it possible in C++ to call `sum()` and `sum (7)` refering to `a` but NOT the call you give as an example...

Comment: so it will skip a and use the default right?? and is it possible to do the same in C++?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `int someValue = sum(b: 14);`?

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi AFAIK C++ can't do that (last time was several years ago that I used C++)... IIRC optional parameters in C++ have to come at the end...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, since .NET 4 Framework this is possible using [Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

```
public int sum(int x = 0, int y = 0)
{
     return x + y;
}
```

Then call it:

```
int sumvalue = sum(y: 15);
```

> **Important:**
>
> Optional parameters are defined at the end of the parameter list,
>   after any required parameters. If the caller provides an argument for
>   any one of a succession of optional parameters, it must provide
>   arguments for all preceding optional parameters. Comma-separated gaps
>   in the argument list are not supported. For example, in the following
>   code, instance method ExampleMethod is defined with one required and
>   two optional parameters

Comment: so it will skip a and use the default right?? and is it possible to do the same in C++?

Comment: Not sure about C++, but in C# this is possible since .NET 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible in C# by using [named and optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

```
public int Sum(int a = 1, int b = 2)
{
    return a + b;
}

Console.WriteLine(Sum(2));    // Writes 4.
Console.WriteLine(Sum());     // Writes 3.
Console.WriteLine(Sum(b: 4)); // Writes 5.
```

This will result in a being set to 2 and b having it's default value, 2. It will always populate the arguments in order, so if you only pass one argument then only a gets set and the rest will use their default values.

```
Sum(2)
```

This will result in a being set to it's default 1 and b being set to it's default 2. As no arguments have been supplied.

```
Sum()
```

This will result in a having it's default value 1, and b being set to 4. The reason order of the arguments is ignored in this case is because we're specifying that b should be set to 4 using a named argument.

```
Sum(b: 4)
```

Comment: so it will skip a and use the default right?? and is it possible to do the same in C++?

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi Won't overloading the method do the trick for you ?