# How to add a Optional Parameter in Visual C# function?

Tags: c#, vb.net, variables, parameters

How can i create a optional parameter in C# as we create in VB.Net

```
Public Sub Demo(ByVal a As Integer,Optional ByVal  b as integer=3)
End Sub
```

I want to declare this in C#

I am using VS2008

Comment: For that feature you need C#4 (VS 2010).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
public void Demo(int a, int b = 3)
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

**Edit:**

If you cannot use optional parameters and don't want to use nullable types, method overloading might do the work:

```
public void Demo(int a)
{
    Demo(a, 3);
}

public void Demo(int a, int b)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Default parameter specifiers are not permitted : Error

Comment: Like @Henk Holterman said in his comment on your question. Optional parameters were introduced in Visual C# 2010. More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: I believe that VB generates overloads for optional parameters internally anyway - so crafting these by hand with C# would lead to the same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void foo(int a, int? b)
{
}
```

You can use function as:

```
foo(4,null)
```

And default parameter in c# [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914858/can-i-give-default-value-to-parameters-in-c-sharp-functions)