# Recursive function that returns the smallest divisor

Tags: c#, recursion

I wrote a function that computes recursively the smallest divisor of an integer n>1:

```
using System;                   
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(SmallestDivisor(n));
    }

    public static int SmallestDivisor(int n)
    {
        return SmallestDivisor(n, 2);
    }

    public static int SmallestDivisor(int n, int d)
    {
        if (n%d == 0)
            return d;
        else  
            return SmallestDivisor(n, d+1);
    }
}
```

My goal is to build a recursive function that takes only the integer n as an argument. Is there any possible alternative to avoid calling another auxiliary function taking as arguments integer n and d?

Comment: Provide a default value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316402/method-overloading-vs-optional-parameter-in-c-sharp-4-0, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914858/can-i-give-a-default-value-to-parameters-or-optional-parameters-in-c-sharp-funct

Comment: If you are learning about the _how_ of recursion then this is ok. But it is a  bad example of _why_ you would use recursion. A simple for-loop would do.

Comment: why does the function have to be recursive? relatively large prime number will give you StackOverflow exception

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm making practice on recursion

Comment: @HenkHolterman, recursion is limited by `n` value: `n` is a divisor of `n`.   but stack size limitation won't allow large n values with this recursive approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for 2 method's one is just enough:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(SmallestDivisor(n));
}

public static int SmallestDivisor(int n, int d=2)
{
    if (n % d == 0)
        return d;
    return SmallestDivisor(n, ++d);
}
```

The parameter `d` is optinal because it has a default value of `2` and you can call the method like `SmallestDivisor(n)`. If you want another value of `d` passed to the method just call `SmallestDivisor(n,d)`.

Comment: Or even `return n % d == 0 ? d : SmallestDivisor(n, ++d);`

Comment: @FunnyBuzer I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
public static int SmallestDivisor(int n, int d)
```

with

```
public static int SmallestDivisor(int n, int d = 2)
```

To provide a default value for `d` and make this parameter optional. Now you can call `SmallestDivisor(n)` or `SmallestDivisor(n,3)`

[Named and Optional Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

recursive method will throw StackOverflow exeption on relatively large prime number (e.g. `15331`). non-recursive solution doesn't have such problem

```
public static int MinimalDivisor(int n)
{
    if ( n % 2 == 0)
        return 2;

    for(int d = 3; d < n/2; d=d+2)
        if (n % d == 0)
           return d;

    return n;
}
```