# What's the name of this kind of method, parameters?

Tags: c#, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you use optional parameters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199761/how-can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-c)

I found in a project where I'm working[language: c#]. A strange signature(at the least for me) like that:

```
AccessModifier NameOfMethod(sometype param1, bool prmFlagOrSomething = false)
```

In the msdn [library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) doesn't exist any reference to this kind of method.
That allow avoid pass the parameter prmFlagOrSomething, in this case prmFlagOrSomething have the value false.

That's what happened, but exist documentation?
What's the real name of this kind of method, or parameter?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a default parameter.  Or as MS calls it, an "Optional Argument":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's just an [Optional Argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)