# .NET Is there such a thing as 'Mandatory Parameter'?

Tags: c#, .net

I know there is [optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199761/how-can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-c) in .NET, but is there a way to force .NET to throw an exception if a parameter is null?

That way I do not have to do parameter null checks on my methods, which clutter the code.

Or is there any other way to enforce non-null parameters on my method signature?, using attribute perhaps?

Comment: Or you could pass non-nullable value types.

Comment: If a parameter is not optional, then it's mandatory - unless there is an overload that doesn't include that parameter then you simply cannot call that method unless you pass a value for that particular parameter. Your definition of "mandatory" seems to be "must not be null" - which is not the same thing, since there is no reason you shouldn't be allowed to pass null as a parameter if null happens to be an accepted value for that parameter.

Comment: Yes, your definition of mandatory is somewhat odd and is certainly not the opposite of optional parameters. In fact it seems completely unrelated to optional parameters.

Comment: And in addition - an optional parameter could still accept a null value, and that would not be "mandatory" according to your definition anymore, so indeed what you're looking for has nothing to do with optional parameters.

Comment: There is no support for this in C#. In the future they *could* add a feature like `public void Add([NotNull] Customer c) { ... }` or `public void Add(Customer c != null) { ... }` or some better syntax. That would/could then be compiled into the same IL as `public void Add(Customer c) { if (c == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("c"); } ... }`. However, I don't think they are going to introduce that. You will have to insert the check manually. You can extract to a method as in Moo-Juice's answer, or use Code Contracts as in Ralf de Kleine's answer.

Comment: You can use some generic tricks to this check; this will make your code compilcated. I think the best approach for this problem is  Design by contract.

Comment: BoltClock, David I understand your point.. and I agree.. however I will leave the title as is because I think that will be the first people search in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Code Contracts.

Ref: [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example from link:

```
void IArray.Insert(int index, Object value)
{
    Contract.Requires(index >= 0);
    Contract.Requires(index <= ((IArray)this).Count);  // For inserting immediately after the end.
    Contract.Ensures(((IArray)this).Count == Contract.OldValue(((IArray)this).Count) + 1);
}
```

Comment: But a `.Requires()` is just a different way to do a 'null check'.

Comment: It's a bit more than a mere 'null check'.

Comment: Thanks for this.., I might use this.. subject to further study.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing out of the box, but I use an extension method to do this:

```
public static class GenericExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Throws an ArgumentNullException if "this" value is default(T)
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">(Inferred) "this" type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="self">"this" value</param>
    /// <param name="variableName">Name of the variable</param>
    /// <returns>"this" value</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">Thrown if "this" value is default(T)</exception>
    public static T ThrowIfDefault<T>(this T self, string variableName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(self, default(T)))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("'{0}' cannot be default(T)", variableName));
        return self;
    }   // eo ThrowIfDefault<T>    
}
```

Usage:

```
public void SomeFunc(string value)
{
    value.ThrowIfDefault("value");
}

public void MyFunc(Guid guid)
{
    guid.ThrowIfDefault("guid");
}
```

It's also useful in class constructors as it returns the value also:

```
public class A
{
}

public class B
{
    private readonly A _a;

    public B(A a)
    {
        _a = a.ThrowIfDefault("a");
    }
}
```

It is also trivial to write one for strings that ensure that not only is it non-null, but that it also has a length,.

Comment: Why did you choose an example with a default value of a non-nullable type, the empty GUID, when he asked about `null`? I do know your method will work for other types too.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, good point.  Have added some additional examples.

Comment: I think you should add `where T : class`

Comment: If he used `where T : class`, it would limit the scope to tests for null references only. In that case `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(self, default(T))` should be simplified to `self == null`. (We assume that no-one overrides `Equals` in a way that makes an instance "equal to" null. That would probably break other things in .NET too.)

Comment: Hey I could use this.. less verbose than doing `if(param == null)` all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the solution is the *combination* of *Code Contracts* (which are very helpful while debugging) and *direct parameter check* for throwing exception in release:

```
void MyMethodWithNotNullValue(Object value) {
  // Contract failure allow you to see the stack, 
  // inspect local variables' values,
  // start debugger etc.
  Contract.Requires(!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value));

  // Unfortunately, contracts can be switched off (usually in release), 
  // so we have to check "value" manually as well
  if (Object.RefrenceEquals(null, value))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("value", "You can't set null to value because...");

  ...
}
```

Comment: So if Contract can be switch off it has no effect? As if the checks are not there? I have no problem with that since we have control over the deployment process.

Comment: When compiling (usually building release) contracts as well as assertions (Debug.Assert) can be switched off (see "Perform Runtime Contract Checking"). Sure, you don't have to switch off contracts in release, but you can do this; that's why I use double check

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into [Aspect oriented programming](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS)

This gives you a before and after method execution.

```
public class LogAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

        Console.WriteLine("Entering [ {0} ] ...", args.Method);

        base.OnEntry(args);
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Leaving [ {0} ] ...", args.Method);

        base.OnExit(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I apply this selectively on the methods I want? I am on the impression this will apply to the entire codebase and there is no way I can customize this per method?

Comment: I don't think so. It's usually used for an abstraction layer.

Answer (score 0):

.net MVC Application when u create a Model of particular Variable at that time you can use like this ............................

**[Required(ErrorMessage = "Department Required")]

```
    public string Department { get; set; }**
```

so when user is forget to add Department at that time it will through exception 
in view u have to also like that  ..................

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Department) 
in view you can write like this

Comment: Yes I know about this, but I am not asking in MVC context.