# Optional Function Parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, optional-parameters

In C# I have the following function definition:

```
public static TResult SomeParentFunctionName<TSource, TResult>(
    TSource SomeValue,
    Func<TSource, TResult> ChildFunction1,
    Func<TSource, TResult> ChildFunction2)
```

This function takes `SomeValue` and then calls `ChildFunction1` and `ChildFunction2`

According to my business rules, I **always** need to run `ChildFunction1`, but only **sometimes** need to run `ChildFunction2`.

Can I make `ChildFunction2` an optional parameter? How do I go about doing that? And how do I know if it has been passed in.

### Options I have considered:

1. I could create two `SomeParentFunctionName` functions, one with `ChildFunction2` and one without.
2. I could pass in a blank function that just won't do anything - but that's not good practice.

Comment: What determines when you need to run `ChildFunction2`? Do you know you have to run it before the call to `SomeParentFunctionName`? Because if so I'd say an overload is probably the most straightforward way to go.

Comment: The user who will be calling `SomeParentFunctionName` already knows if `ChildFunction2` will be called. Right. That's one of my considerations. Can you think of another way to do it?

Comment: You could pass in `null` (which I've never liked) or use an [optional parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) and set it to null which is slightly cleaner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you use optional parameters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199761/how-can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-c)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, just set it to null:

```
public static TResult SomeParentFunctionName<TSource, TResult>(
    TSource SomeValue,
    Func<TSource, TResult> ChildFunction1, 
    Func<TSource, TResult> ChildFunction2 = null)
{
    ...
    if (ChildFunction2 != null)
        ChildFunction2();
}
```

If you want to pass in a func for `ChildFunction2`, go ahead and do it. If you don't want to pass anything for it just omit it when calling the function.

This is actually exactly what you were calling it - [optional argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is a 3rd option. Use the `params` keyword to indicate that the function takes a variable number of arguments. But, then you need to handle the case where no `Func<TSource, TResult>` objects are passed.

If your always going to need either 1 or 2 `Func<TSource, TResult>` objects, then overloading the function as you suggest in option 1 is the most common way to handle the situation.

Comment: Thanks this IS another option.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I make ChildFunction2 an optional parameter?

Sure, just give a default value of `null`:

```
public static TResult SomeParentFunctionName<TSource, TResult>(
       TSource SomeValue,
       Func<TSource, TResult> ChildFunction1,
       Func<TSource, TResult> ChildFunction2 = null)
```

then just check for `null`:

```
{
    TResult res = ChildFunction1(source);

    if(ChildFunction2 != null)
        TResult res2 = ChildFunction1(source2);

}
```