# (Discord.Net) Pass a user to a command

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am currently coding a discord bot in discord.net. The command that I'm having trouble with is one that can display information about a user. If no parameter is given I already have it set up to display info about the current user.

```
    [Command("userinfo")]
    public async Task userinfo(IUser user = ???)
```

How would I pass a user here? I am using discord.net v1.0.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you use optional parameters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199761/how-can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you simply have to set a default value for user, I recommend to use SocketUser instead of IUser.

Here is a code example:

```
    [Command("userinfo")]
    public async Task UserInfo(SocketUser user = null)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = Context.User;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between `IUser` and `SocketUser`?

Comment: IUser is a Interface, SocketUser not ;) basicially u can do "more" with SocketUser because you can use the methods on SocketUser :) it works good for me