# Given these three similar methods, how we can condense them into a single method?

Tags: c#

```
public int Add2(int a, int b) => a + b;
public int Add3(int a, int b, int c) => a + b + c;
public int Add4 (int a,int b,int c,int d) => a + b + c + d;
```

How can we write these methods under a single method?

Comment: Please fix your formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you use optional parameters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199761/how-can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-c) - `public int Add(int a, int b, int c=0, int d=0)`, I would guess.

Answer (score 12):

Use `params int[]` in your Add method and you can add as many numbers as you'd like.

Something like:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));      
    }

    public static int Add(params int[] numbers) 
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (int n in numbers)
        {
            sum += n;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
15
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PbVpfM)

### Enhancement

With `Linq`, the code get's shorter

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));      
    }

    public static int Add(params int[] numbers) 
    {
        return numbers.Sum();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
15
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XSqjOk)

Comment: This is a much nicer solution than default params. I was thinking of something similar, but I couldn't think of an easy way to implement

Comment: Thnks for replay

Comment: @DevaraneniLaxmanRao Kindly check the answer, if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try optional arguments.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments

Write a method A with

```
Add (int a, int b, int c = 0, int d = 0) { }
```

Then based on value passed in c and d param do calculation.

Comment: Thnks for replay

Answer (score 1):

The value `a` and `b` are always used in three functions. These values are mandatory in your function. The value `c` and `d` aren't always used. If you want to combine all of the functions, just make these values optional by giving them default value.

```
public int Add(int a, int b, int c = 0, int d = 0){
    return a + b + c + d;
}
```

Comment: Thnks for replay

Answer (score 1):

Yet-another-way..fun with `Func` and (also) `Linq` :)

```
static Func<int[], int> Add = ((i) => i.Sum());

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Add.Invoke(new[] {1,2,3,4,5}));

    Console.WriteLine(Add.Invoke(new[] {8}));

    Console.WriteLine(Add.Invoke(new[] {-2, -4, 6}));
}

//15
//8
//0
```