# C#: How can you skip former arguments when using a function if there are multiple arguments that has default value

Tags: c#, arguments, optional-parameters

I have a function:

```
void func(string a = "hi", int b = 2, float c = 3f) {
  // return whatever
}
```

Say in a case I want to use the function but I only know b's value in this case, can I still use this func? How?
The following code would compare my input with a which causes error:

```
func(4);
```

Is there a way to pass in value to a particular argument(the 2nd one) and still use default values for the one on the left?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works but how about if you used named parameters eg. `func( b: 4 )`

Comment: @EpicKip, `'hi'` is not a valid C# string.

Comment: Sorry, should be "hi".

Comment: Missed that @John And Orel Eraki :)

Comment: There's a lot of answers in the linked question, but the second half of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29820290/3181933) fits the bill.