# Passing optional parameters to method

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass optional parameter to method and having hard times understanding why it doesn't work. As most popular answer here ([How can you use optional parameters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199761/how-can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-c)) says `public void SomeMethod(int a, int b = 0)`. So I have tried the same below.

Can I get rid of `else` statement here? I mean can I use parameter that is otherwise `=""` if not something else = optional? If it exists, method will get it, if not then skip it?

Here is code with else statement that works (https://dotnetfiddle.net/sy5FW5):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        int MyNumber = 6;
        string StringOne;
        string StringTwo;

        if (MyNumber != 5)
        {
            StringOne = "Number is not 5";
            StringTwo = "True that!";
        }
        else
        {
            StringOne = "";
            StringTwo = "";
        }
        CheckNumber(StringOne, StringTwo);
    }

    public static void CheckNumber(string StringOne, string StringTwo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(StringOne + "\n" + StringTwo);
    }
}
```

Above code is what I need and it is working fine. My question is more like is there any better way?

Here is what I was thinking of, but it does not work:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        int MyNumber = 6;
        string StringOne;
        string StringTwo;

        if (MyNumber != 5)
        {
            StringOne = "Number is not 5";
            StringTwo = "True that!";
        }
        CheckNumber(StringOne, StringTwo);
    }

    public static void CheckNumber(string StringOne = "", string StringTwo = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(StringOne + "\n" + StringTwo);
    }
}
```

Variables are not assigned in: `CheckNumber(StringOne, StringTwo);`

I was thinking that I can make parameters optional by using `string StringOne = ""` but it does not seem to be the solution?

Comment: Call `CheckNumber()` to use optioanal.

Comment: What you have is fine.

Comment: "optional" means that you can leave out the parameter in the method call, not that it will use that default value when you supply "something empty"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your particular case, you don't need to make the parameters of your method optional, you just need to initialize your variables to the default value you want to use:

```
    int MyNumber = 6;
    string StringOne = "";  // <--
    string StringTwo = "";  // <--

    if (MyNumber != 5)
    {
        StringOne = "Number is not 5";
        StringTwo = "True that!";
    }
    CheckNumber(StringOne, StringTwo);
```

A word of caution: Please do not take that as an invitation to go ahead and explicitly initialize all your variables. This should be done only when there is a good reason to do so, because it increases the chance of *"I forgot to set this variable to the correct value"* type of bugs (which would otherwise be caught by the assignment check of the C# compiler).

Comment: This works, but obviously it is less efficient (by some tiny amount) than using if/else, since if MyNumber is not 5, the strings are first initialised to "" and then reassigned to other strings. I would advise the OP to keep their code as it is.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: That depends on the OP's use case. In many cases, readability and code simplicity are much more important than tiny performance micro-optimizations.

Comment: I agree that code clarity is important, which is why I personally prefer the explicit if/else in cases such as this. YMMV.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I do agree that variable initializations should be used sparingly (see my current edit to my answer).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to initialise pairs of items is to use the C#8 "tuple" syntax, for example:

```
int MyNumber = 6;

(string StringOne, string StringTwo) = 
    MyNumber != 5 ? ("Number is not 5", "True that!")
                  : ("",                ""          );

CheckNumber(StringOne, StringTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `string` is a reference type and the default value for all reference types is null.

Try to init the StringOne and StringTwo to String.empty