# How to pass orderby parameter value to a lambda function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, unit-of-work

I am using this pattern 
https://gist.github.com/pmbanugo/8456744#file-ientityrepository-cs 
and function is

```
IEnumerable<T> GetAll(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = null
            );
```

I want to pass parametere `orderBy`

`_unitOfWork.GetAll(/*please pass orderby paramter here*/);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you use optional parameters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199761/how-can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-c)

Comment: no ! I can't pass argument to a lambda expression type function. which is more complex than what you shared. thanks @phuzi

Answer (score 1):

Use named arguments to only pass the `orderBy` argument with a sorting function.

```
_unitOfWork.GetAll(orderBy: x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Something));
```

Comment: its not working sorry