# Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments, default-parameters

I would like a JavaScript function to have optional arguments which I set a default on, which get used if the value isn't defined (and ignored if the value is passed). In Ruby you can do it like this:

```
def read_file(file, delete_after = false)
  # code
end
```

Does this work in JavaScript?

```
function read_file(file, delete_after = false) {
  // Code
}
```

Comment: from `ES6` this will work `function read_file(file, delete_after=false){};`

Answer (score 3571, accepted):

From [ES6/ES2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), default parameters are in the language specification.

```
function read_file(file, delete_after = false) {
  // Code
}
```

just works.

Reference: [Default Parameters - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters)

> Default function parameters allow formal parameters to be initialized with default values if **no value** or **undefined** is passed.

In ES6, you can [simulate default *named* parameters via destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_parameter-handling.html#sec_named-parameters):

```
// the `= {}` below lets you call the function without any parameters
function myFor({ start = 5, end = 1, step = -1 } = {}) { // (A)
    // Use the variables `start`, `end` and `step` here
    ···
}

// sample call using an object
myFor({ start: 3, end: 0 });

// also OK
myFor();
myFor({});
```

**Pre ES2015**,

There are a lot of ways, but this is my preferred method — it lets you pass in anything you want, including false or null. (`typeof null == "object"`)

```
function foo(a, b) {
  a = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : 42;
  b = typeof b !== 'undefined' ? b : 'default_b';
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can also encapsulate it as such: `function defaultFor(arg, val) { return typeof arg !== 'undefined' ? arg : val; }` and then you can call it as `a = defaultFor(a, 42);`

Comment: This is too slow, use `a = ((a != null) ? a : 42);`.

Comment: @SiPlus then it is **not** anymore default value and there's no point other than quickly changing a lot of values passed to functions (_like using defined constants in place of `null`_). Basically your code _translates_ `null` to `42`. If `a` is `undefined` in your example then it will _stay_ `undefined` and it is not getting any default value.

Comment: @Sampo `undefined==null` (but not `===null`). But if you intentionally pass `null` to the function, my code will not work.

Comment: @SiPlus and you got extra reference errors for free of charge while trying to use `undefined` objects :p Even while it may work with some browsers and might be faster, `null` is still an object and `undefined` is reference to primitive type that is trying to tell that there is nothing here, not even `null`. See here, both cases in nutshell: [JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

Comment: if you check against the property of an object, then `typeof` is redundant. `function foo(data) { var bar = data.bar !== undefined ? data.bar : 'default'; }` This won't throw reference errors and is concise.

Comment: This didn't work for me. If you pass in no value you can't use typeof on the parameter. You have to instead use `var === undefined`

Comment: I know it's really minor, but I don't like how you are assigning `a = a` and `b = b` when those parameters are not undefined. Also, that ternary operator with a bit complicated condition may be hard to read for future maintainers.
I would prefer following syntax:
`if (typeof a == 'undefined') a = 42`
- no unnecessary assignment plus a little bit easier to read.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `typeof`? It would seem simpler to just do `a === undefined`. Plus that way you'd get a reference error if you misspelled `undefined` vs. putting it in a string.

Comment: @AbeVoelker There were some problems with `undefined` not being a keyword in older javascript engines - so you could overwrite it. You can always generate an undefined by using `void` - for example: `a = a !== void 0 ? a : "Default";` - it is ugly, and there is something fundamentally wrong with the code overwriting undefined anyway.

Comment: @Sebi Also that's how it roughly looks when you compile/preprocess TypeScript function with parameters having a default value.

Comment: why not simply using the less cryptic `if (typeof a === 'undefined') a = 42;`?

Comment: you can use `a = a || 42;` it's more easy

Comment: FYI: MS Edge and IE11 throw an error when assigning a default value like so: function badArg(imOK, imNOT='') {} - it will balk at the  ='' - didn't test null, just removed it because it wasn't actually necessary.

Comment: Note that setting defaults in the parameter declaration doesn't currently work in mobile Safari or Chrome.

Comment: You can simply write

function foo(a, b)
{
  a = a || 42;
  b = b || 'default_b';
  ...
}

Comment: I suggest updating your answer to warn about the gotchas with using default parameter values.  See my post below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function/46760685#46760685

Comment: According to this, default parameters are now supported by most browsers (including mobile), IE being the exception: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters#Browser_compatibility and http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: You can also use default value assignment with the [destructuring assignment notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: +1 This particular Q&A is a perfect example of the fact that the majority of developers will come to SO before anywhere else. :)

Comment: by calling `myFor()` won't init `start` and `end` right? So both of them will be `undefined` in the function.

Answer (score 633):

```
function read_file(file, delete_after) {
    delete_after = delete_after || "my default here";
    //rest of code
}
```

This assigns to `delete_after` the value of `delete_after` if it is not a *falsey* value otherwise it assigns the string `"my default here"`. For more detail, check out [Doug Crockford's survey of the language and check out the section on Operators](http://crockford.com/javascript/survey.html).

This approach does not work if you want to pass in a *falsey* value i.e. `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `0` or `""`. If you require *falsey* values to be passed in you would need to use the method in [Tom Ritter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/how-do-i-make-a-default-value-for-a-parameter-to-a-javascript-function/894877#894877).

When dealing with a number of parameters to a function, it is often useful to allow the consumer to pass the parameter arguments in an object and then *merge* these values with an object that contains the default values for the function

```
function read_file(values) {
    values = merge({ 
        delete_after : "my default here"
    }, values || {});

    // rest of code
}

// simple implementation based on $.extend() from jQuery
function merge() {
    var obj, name, copy,
        target = arguments[0] || {},
        i = 1,
        length = arguments.length;

    for (; i < length; i++) {
        if ((obj = arguments[i]) != null) {
            for (name in obj) {
                copy = obj[name];

                if (target === copy) {
                    continue;
                }
                else if (copy !== undefined) {
                    target[name] = copy;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return target;
};
```

to use

```
// will use the default delete_after value
read_file({ file: "my file" }); 

// will override default delete_after value
read_file({ file: "my file", delete_after: "my value" });
```

Comment: I find this insufficient, because I may want to pass in false.

Comment: I find it's adequate for most situations

Comment: Because it doesn't work for falsey values, it may create a maintenance  nightmare.  A bit of code that has always been passed truthy values before and suddenly fails because a falsey one is passed in should probably be avoided where a more robust approach is available.

Comment: How come, in this case, `delete_after` doesn't get the boolean result of the expression `delete_after || "my default value"`?

Comment: @xbonez it assigns to `delete_after` the value of `delete_after` if it is not a _falsey_ value otherwise it assigns the string `my default here`. For more detail, check out Doug Crockford's survey of the lanugage and check out the section on **Operators** - http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html

Comment: Here is the catch : 
"This approach does not work if you want to pass in a falsey value i.e. false, null, undefined, 0 or "". If you require falsey values to be passed in you would need to use the method in Tom Ritter's answer."

Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It may not work if you need falsey values but my functions will frequently take an optional options object.  This is perfect for that use case:  `opts = opts || {}`.

Comment: This may be better this way: `delete_after = typeof(delete_after) != 'undefined' ? delete_after : "my default here";`

Comment: or, you could just default to a falsey value - which is generally a good default anyway (eg., false for bools, empty string for strings, 0 for numbers, etc.) - in which case it doesn't really matter what was passed in.

Comment: This works for variebles as well as objects. Thank you.

Comment: The first example is not universal because that won't work for the case with a method like `setValue(v)` if you pass `0` where `v` should be `1` by default. It will work with strings and objects only.

Answer (score 158):

I find something simple like this to be much more concise and readable personally.

```
function pick(arg, def) {
   return (typeof arg == 'undefined' ? def : arg);
}

function myFunc(x) {
  x = pick(x, 'my default');
}
```

Comment: Update: If you're using **underscore.js** already I find it even better to use `_.defaults(iceCream, {flavor: "vanilla", sprinkles: "lots"});`. Using the global namespace as shown in this answer is by many considered a bad practice. You may also consider rolling your own utility for this common task (eg. `util.default(arg, "defaul value")`) if don't want to use underscore, but I mostly end up using underscore sooner or later anyway no point in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @andersand I like the idea of something like `util.default(arg, "defaul value")) ` would you or @tj111 mind posting a quick demo?

Comment: I actually recommend this one, i use it and call it "por" which stands for "parameter or"

Comment: Don't say typeof arg == 'undefined', instead say arg === undefined

Comment: @OsamaBinLogin what you say is correct for current JS - the older test persists because on some browsers it used to be possible to overwrite `undefined` with some other value, causing the test to fail.

Comment: @Alnitak: It's still possible to override `undefined`.  So, it's still a good idea to use `typeof` and `'undefined'`.

Comment: @LS  It's no longer possible to create a global variable named `undefined`. 
It's only possible to create a local variable or function parameter of that name, and if you introduce one of those into your function's lexical scope you've only got yourself to blame.

Answer (score 68):

In ECMAScript 6 you will actually be able to write exactly what you have:

```
function read_file(file, delete_after = false) {
  // Code
}
```

This will set `delete_after` to `false` if it s not present or `undefined`. You can use ES6 features like this one today with transpilers such as [Babel](http://babeljs.io/).

[See the MDN article for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

Comment: Waiting for browser any get ECMAScript 6

Comment: What would Babel transpile this to?

Comment: @harryg: http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20read_file(file%2C%20delete_after%20%3D%20false)%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Code%0A%7D

Comment: Here is the compatibility table for ES6 https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#default_function_parameters Unfortunately this syntax **isn't supported yet**.

Comment: Edge14 and and current Chrome and Opera support it now, along with FF from last year... now just waiting on Safari, which supports it in the current beta, so hopefully in ~4 months the latest versions of all browsers will support it. Then you'll just have to wait for your users to actually update their browsers (or push them to do so.)

Answer (score 33):

**Default Parameter Values**

With ES6, you can do perhaps one of the most common idioms in `JavaScript` relates to setting a default  value for a function parameter. The way we’ve done this for years should look quite  familiar:

```
function foo(x,y) {
 x = x || 11;
 y = y || 31;
 console.log( x + y );
}
foo(); // 42
foo( 5, 6 ); // 11
foo( 5 ); // 36
foo( null, 6 ); // 17
```

This pattern is most used, but is dangerous when we pass values like

```
foo(0, 42)
foo( 0, 42 ); // 53 <-- Oops, not 42
```

Why? Because the `0 is falsy`, and so the `x || 11 results in 11`, not the directly passed  in 0. To fix this gotcha, some people will instead write the check more verbosely like this:

```
function foo(x,y) {
 x = (x !== undefined) ? x : 11;
 y = (y !== undefined) ? y : 31;
 console.log( x + y );
}
foo( 0, 42 ); // 42
foo( undefined, 6 ); // 17
```

we can now examine a nice helpful syntax added as of `ES6` to  streamline the assignment of default values to missing arguments:

```
function foo(x = 11, y = 31) {
 console.log( x + y );
}

foo(); // 42
foo( 5, 6 ); // 11
foo( 0, 42 ); // 42
foo( 5 ); // 36
foo( 5, undefined ); // 36 <-- `undefined` is missing
foo( 5, null ); // 5 <-- null coerces to `0`
foo( undefined, 6 ); // 17 <-- `undefined` is missing
foo( null, 6 ); // 6 <-- null coerces to `0`
```

`x = 11` in a function declaration is more like `x !== undefined ? x : 11` than the  much more common idiom `x || 11`

**Default Value Expressions**

`Function` default values can be more than just simple values like 31; they can be any  valid expression, even a `function call`:

```
function bar(val) {
 console.log( "bar called!" );
 return y + val;
}
function foo(x = y + 3, z = bar( x )) {
 console.log( x, z );
}
var y = 5;
foo(); // "bar called"
 // 8 13
foo( 10 ); // "bar called"
 // 10 15
y = 6;
foo( undefined, 10 ); // 9 10
```

As you can see, the default value expressions are lazily evaluated, meaning they’re  only run if and when they’re needed — that is, when a parameter’s argument is omitted or is undefined.

A default value expression can  even be an inline function expression call — commonly referred to as an Immediately  Invoked Function Expression `(IIFE)`:

```
function foo( x =
 (function(v){ return v + 11; })( 31 )
) {
 console.log( x );
}
foo(); // 42
```

Answer (score 16):

that solution is work for me in js:

```
function read_file(file, delete_after) {
    delete_after = delete_after || false;
    // Code
}
```

Comment: What happens if `delete_after` is ``0`` or ``null``? It will not work correct for these cases.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter it only would be true in some cases. But if you only want the default values to unset values this didn't work, because 0 or null !=== false.

Comment: @Rutrus: I don't understand anything you just said.

Answer (score 12):

I would highly recommend extreme caution when using default parameter values in javascript.  It often creates bugs when used in conjunction with higher order functions like `forEach`, `map`, and `reduce`.  For example, consider this line of code:

```js
['1', '2', '3'].map(parseInt); // [1, NaN, NaN]
```

parseInt has an optional second parameter `function parseInt(s, [`**radix**`=10])` but map calls `parseInt` with three arguments: (*element*, *index*, and *array*).

I suggest you separate your required parameters form your optional/default valued arguments.  If your function takes 1,2, or 3 required parameters for which no default value makes sense, make them positional parameters to the function, any optional parameters should follow as named attributes of a single object. If your function takes 4 or more, perhaps it makes more sense to supply all arguments via attributes of a single object parameter.

In your case I would suggest you write your deleteFile function like this: (*edited per* `instead`'s *comments*)...

```js
// unsafe
function read_file(fileName, deleteAfter=false) {
    if (deleteAfter) {
        console.log(`Reading and then deleting ${fileName}`);
    } else {
        console.log(`Just reading ${fileName}`);
    }
}

// better
function readFile(fileName, options) {
  const deleteAfter = !!(options && options.deleteAfter === true);
  read_file(fileName, deleteAfter);
}

console.log('unsafe...');
['log1.txt', 'log2.txt', 'log3.txt'].map(read_file);

console.log('better...');
['log1.txt', 'log2.txt', 'log3.txt'].map(readFile);
```

Running the above snippet illustrates the dangers lurking behind default argument values for unused parameters.

Comment: This "better solution" is quite unreadable. I would rather recommend to check variable type like `typeof deleteAfter === 'bool'` and throw Exception otherwise. Plus in case of using methods like map/foreach etc. just use them with caution and wrap called functions with anonymous function. `['1', '2', '3'].map((value) => {read_file(value);})`

Comment: That's a good point.  I was trying to avoid using libraries in my code snippet, but this idiom is quite messy in pure javascript.  Personally, I would use lodash's `get` method to retrieve deleteAfter.  Throwing an exception if `typeof 'deleteAfter' !== 'bool'` may also be a good prudent measure.  I don't like designing methods that require the caller to "use caution".  Caution is the responsibility of the function, not the caller.  The end behavior should follow the principle of least surprise.

Comment: I agree, that method shouldn't be wrote the way, that calling it, can broke its behavior. But keep in mind that function is like model, and caller is like controller. Model should take care of data processing. Function (method) should expect that data, can be passed wrong way and handle it. That's why checking type of parameter plus throwing Exception, is the best way. Even though it's more complex. But still it can save You from scratching Your head and keep asking... WHY IT IS NOT WORKING?! and then... WHY IT IS WORKING?!

Answer (score 11):

Just use an explicit comparison with undefined.

```
function read_file(file, delete_after)
{
    if(delete_after === undefined) { delete_after = false; }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As an update...with ECMAScript 6 you can **FINALLY** set default values in function parameter declarations like so:

```
function f (x, y = 7, z = 42) {
  return x + y + z
}

f(1) === 50
```

As referenced by - http://es6-features.org/#DefaultParameterValues

Comment: This answer is not useful because it is a duplicate

Answer (score 9):

being a long time C++ developer (Rookie to web development :)), when I first came across this situation, I did the parameter assignment in the function definition, like it is mentioned in the question, as follows.

```
function myfunc(a,b=10)
```

But beware that it doesn't work consistently across browsers. For me it worked on chrome on my desktop, but did not work on chrome on android.
Safer option, as many have mentioned above is -

```
    function myfunc(a,b)
    {
    if (typeof(b)==='undefined') b = 10;
......
    }
```

Intention for this answer is not to repeat the same solutions, what others have already mentioned, but to inform that parameter assignment in the function definition may work on some browsers, but don't rely on it.

Comment: Assignment within the function definition also doesn't work in IE 11, which is the most current version of IE for Windows 8.1.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, `function myfunc(a,b=10)` is ES6 syntax, there are links to compatibility tables in other answers.

Answer (score 8):

To anyone interested in having there code work in Microsoft Edge, do not use defaults in function parameters.

```
function read_file(file, delete_after = false) {
    #code
}
```

In that example Edge will throw an error "Expecting ')'"

To get around this use

```
function read_file(file, delete_after) {
  if(delete_after == undefined)
  {
    delete_after = false;
  }
  #code
}
```

As of Aug 08 2016 this is still an issue

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `ES6+` you can set default parameters in the following manner:

```js
function test (foo = 1, bar = 2) {
  console.log(foo, bar);
}

test(5); // foo gets overwritten, bar remains default parameter
```

If you need `ES5` syntax you can do it in the following manner:

```js
function test(foo, bar) {
  foo = foo || 2;
  bar = bar || 0;
  
  console.log(foo, bar);
}

test(5); // foo gets overwritten, bar remains default parameter
```

In the above syntax the `OR` operator is used. The `OR` operator always returns the first value if this can be converted to `true` if not it returns the righthandside value. When the function is called with no corresponding argument the parameter variable (`bar` in  our example) is set to `undefined` by the JS engine. `undefined` Is then converted to false and thus does the `OR` operator return the value 0.

Answer (score 6):

```
function helloWorld(name, symbol = '!!!') {
    name = name || 'worlds';
    console.log('hello ' + name + symbol);
}

helloWorld(); // hello worlds!!!

helloWorld('john'); // hello john!!!

helloWorld('john', '(>.<)'); // hello john(>.<)

helloWorld('john', undefined); // hello john!!!

helloWorld(undefined, undefined); // hello worlds!!!
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this if you want to use latest **`ECMA6`** syntax:

```js
function myFunction(someValue = "This is DEFAULT!") {
  console.log("someValue --> ", someValue);
}

myFunction("Not A default value") // calling the function without default value
myFunction()  // calling the function with default value
```

It is called [`default function parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). It allows formal parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or undefined is passed.
**NOTE**: It wont work with Internet Explorer or older browsers.

For maximum possible **compatibility** use this:

```js
function myFunction(someValue) {
  someValue = (someValue === undefined) ? "This is DEFAULT!" : someValue;
  console.log("someValue --> ", someValue);
}

myFunction("Not A default value") // calling the function without default value
myFunction()  // calling the function with default value
```

Both functions have exact same behavior as each of these example rely on the fact that the parameter variable will be `undefined` if no parameter value was passed when calling that function.

Comment: NOTE: as @BlackBeard says, function(param=value) WONT work with IE. Use the compatible version.

Answer (score 6):

**ES6:** As already mentioned in most answers, in ES6, you can simply initialise a parameter along with a value.

---

**ES5:** Most of the given answers aren't good enough for me because there are occasions where I may have to pass falsey values such as `0`, `null` and `undefined` to a function. To determine if a parameter is undefined because that's the value I passed instead of undefined due to not have been defined at all I do this:

```
function foo (param1, param2) {
   param1 = arguments.length >= 1 ? param1 : "default1";
   param2 = arguments.length >= 2 ? param2 : "default2";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As per the syntax

```
function [name]([param1[ = defaultValue1 ][, ..., paramN[ = defaultValueN ]]]) {
   statements
}
```

you can define the default value of formal parameters.
and also check undefined value by using **typeof** function.

Answer (score 5):

```js
function throwIfNoValue() {
throw new Error('Missing argument');
}
function foo(argValue = throwIfNoValue()) {
return argValue ;
}
```

Here foo() is a function which has a parameter named argValue. If we don’t pass anything in the function call here, then the function throwIfNoValue() will be called and the returned result will be assigned to the only argument argValue. This is how a function call can be used as a default parameter. Which makes the code more simplified and readable.

[This example has been taken from here](http://anjandutta.com/javascript-es6-default-parameter/)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, using default parameters is fully supported in **ES6**:

```
function read_file(file, delete_after = false) {
  // Code
}
```

or

```
const read_file = (file, delete_after = false) => {
    // Code
}
```

but prior in **ES5** you could easily do this:

```
function read_file(file, delete_after) {
  var df = delete_after || false;
  // Code
}
```

Which means if the value is there, use the value, otherwise, use the second value after `||` operation which does the same thing...

**Note:** also there is a big difference between those if you pass a value to **ES6** one even the value be falsy, that will be replaced with new value, something like `null` or `""`... but **ES5** one only will be replaced if only the passed value is truthy, that's because the way `||` working...

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason you are **not** on ES6 and **are** using [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) here is a concise way to default function parameters via [`_.defaultTo`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#defaultTo) method:

```js
var fn = function(a, b) {
  a = _.defaultTo(a, 'Hi')
  b = _.defaultTo(b, 'Mom!')

  console.log(a, b)
}

fn()                 // Hi Mom!
fn(undefined, null)  // Hi Mom!
fn(NaN, NaN)         // Hi Mom!
fn(1)                // 1 "Mom!"
fn(null, 2)          // Hi 2
fn(false, false)     // false false
fn(0, 2)             // 0 2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Which will set the default if the current value is **NaN**, **null**, or **undefined**

Answer (score 4):

### Sounds of Future

In future, you will be able to "spread" one object to another (currently as of 2019 [NOT supported by Edge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)!) - demonstration how to use that for nice default options regardless of order:

```js
function test(options) {
    var options = {
       // defaults
       url: 'defaultURL',
       some: 'somethingDefault',
       // override with input options
       ...options
    };
    
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.innerHTML += '<br>' + options.url + ' : ' + options.some;
}
test();
test({});
test({url:'myURL'});
test({some:'somethingOfMine'});
test({url:'overrideURL', some:'andSomething'});
test({url:'overrideURL', some:'andSomething', extra:'noProblem'});
```

MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

...meanwhile what [Edge DOES support is Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility) (IE does not, but I really hope we can leave IE behind :) )

Similarly you could do

```js
    function test(options) {
        var options = Object.assign({
           // defaults
           url: 'defaultURL',
           some: 'somethingDefault',
        }, options); // override with input options
        
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.innerHTML += '<br>' + options.url + ' : ' + options.some;
    }
    test();
    test({});
    test({url:'myURL'});
    test({some:'somethingOfMine'});
    test({url:'overrideURL', some:'andSomething'});
    test({url:'overrideURL', some:'andSomething', extra:'noProblem'});
```

**EDIT:** Due to comments regarding `const` options - the problem with using constant options in the rest of the function is actually **not** that you can't do that, is just that you can't use the constant variable in its own declaration - you would have to adjust the input naming to something like

```
function test(input_options){
   const options = {
     // defaults
     someKey:    'someDefaultValue',
     anotherKey: 'anotherDefaultValue',

     // merge-in input options
     ...input_options
   };

   // from now on use options with no problem
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you normal never want to do that as this will re assign options which is already defined but you can use it with a other var that would be legit.

Comment: function test(options) {  /* Options is defined it will throw a error if you use const options = {} now*/ }

Comment: no not global when you create a function and you pass in as argument name options then inside the function options is defined inside function (opt) {} opt is defined you can't use const opt inside that function then this is bad because you do variable reassignment if you do that often and it looks like your general pattern this is a issue

Comment: @google-frank-dspeed ah, do you mean that you can't do `function(opt){ const opt =   /*some merging*/; }` ? **That for sure won't work because you would use `const` variable *before it was declared*** - you would have to adjust - `function test(input_opt){ const opt = { someKey: 'someDefaultValue', ...input_opt} }`

Comment: @google-frank-dspeed anyway more new people will probably wonder about this, so I've added the how-to code to edit :) so thanks for pointing that out for others :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to showcase my skills too (lol), above function can written even without having named arguments as below:

**ES5 and above**

```
function foo() {
    a = typeof arguments[0] !== 'undefined' ? a : 42;
    b = typeof arguments[1] !== 'undefined' ? b : 'default_b';
    ...
}
```

**ES6 and above**

```
function foo(...rest) {
    a = typeof rest[0] !== 'undefined' ? a : 42;
    b = typeof rest[1] !== 'undefined' ? b : 'default_b';
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Yes - proof:

```js
function read_file(file, delete_after = false) {
  // Code
  console.log({file,delete_after});
}



// TEST
read_file("A");
read_file("B",true);
read_file("C",false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this is referred to as a default parameter

Default function parameters allow formal parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or undefined is passed.

Syntax:

```
function [name]([param1[ = defaultValue1 ][, ..., paramN[ = defaultValueN ]]]) {
   statements
}
```

**Description:**

Parameters of functions default to undefined However, in situations it might be useful to set a different default value.  This is where default parameters can help.

In the past, the general strategy for setting defaults was to test parameter values in the body of the function and assign a value if they are undefined.  If no value is provided in the call, its value would be undefined.  You would have to set a conditional check to make sure the parameter is not undefined

With default parameters in ES2015, the check in the function body is no longer necessary.  Now you can simply put a default value in the function head.

Example of the differences:

```
// OLD METHOD
function multiply(a, b) {
  b = (typeof b !== 'undefined') ?  b : 1;
  return a * b;
}

multiply(5, 2); // 10
multiply(5, 1); // 5
multiply(5);    // 5


// NEW METHOD
function multiply(a, b = 1) {
  return a * b;
}

multiply(5, 2); // 10
multiply(5, 1); // 5
multiply(5);    // 5
```

**Different Syntax Examples:**

Padding undefined vs other falsy values:

Even if the value is set explicitly when calling, the value of the num argument is the default one.

```
function test(num = 1) {
  console.log(typeof num);
}

test();          // 'number' (num is set to 1)
test(undefined); // 'number' (num is set to 1 too)

// test with other falsy values:
test('');        // 'string' (num is set to '')
test(null);      // 'object' (num is set to null)
```

Evaluated at call time:

The default argument gets evaluated at call time, so unlike some other languages, a new object is created each time the function is called.

```
function append(value, array = []) {
  array.push(value);
  return array;
}

append(1); //[1]
append(2); //[2], not [1, 2]


// This even applies to functions and variables
function callSomething(thing = something()) {
 return thing;
}

function something() {
  return 'sth';
}

callSomething();  //sth
```

Default parameters are available to later default parameters:

Params already encountered are available to later default parameters

```
function singularAutoPlural(singular, plural = singular + 's',
                        rallyingCry = plural + ' ATTACK!!!') {
  return [singular, plural, rallyingCry];
}

//["Gecko","Geckos", "Geckos ATTACK!!!"]
singularAutoPlural('Gecko');

//["Fox","Foxes", "Foxes ATTACK!!!"]
singularAutoPlural('Fox', 'Foxes');

//["Deer", "Deer", "Deer ... change."]
singularAutoPlural('Deer', 'Deer', 'Deer peaceably and respectfully \ petition the government for positive change.')
```

Functions defined inside function body:

Introduced in Gecko 33 (Firefox 33 / Thunderbird 33 / SeaMonkey 2.30). Functions declared in the function body cannot be referred inside default parameters and throw a ReferenceError (currently a TypeError in SpiderMonkey, see bug 1022967). Default parameters are always executed first, function declarations inside the function body evaluate afterwards.

```
// Doesn't work! Throws ReferenceError.
function f(a = go()) {
  function go() { return ':P'; }
}
```

Parameters without defaults after default parameters:

Prior to Gecko 26 (Firefox 26 / Thunderbird 26 / SeaMonkey 2.23 / Firefox OS 1.2), the following code resulted in a SyntaxError. This has been fixed in bug 777060 and works as expected in later versions. Parameters are still set left-to-right, overwriting default parameters even if there are later parameters without defaults.

```
function f(x = 1, y) {
  return [x, y];
}

f(); // [1, undefined]
f(2); // [2, undefined]
```

Destructured paramet with default value assignment:

You can use default value assignment with the destructuring assignment notation

```
function f([x, y] = [1, 2], {z: z} = {z: 3}) {
  return x + y + z;
}

f(); // 6
```

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed a few answers mentioning that using default params isn't portable to other browsers, but it's only fair to point out that you can use transpilers like Babel to convert your code into ES5 syntax for browsers that have limited support for modern JS features.

So this:

```
function read_file(file, delete_after = false) {
  // Code
}
```

would be transpiled as this (try it out in the Babel REPL -> https://babeljs.io/repl/):

```
"use strict";

function read_file(file) {

  var delete_after =
    arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : false;
  
  //Code...

}
```

Of course, if you have no intention of using transpilation, then setting default params in the body of the function like others have demonstrated is perfectly fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just a different approach to set default params is to use object map of arguments, instead of arguments directly.
For example,

```
const defaultConfig = {
 category: 'Animals',
 legs: 4
};

function checkOrganism(props) {
 const category = props.category || defaultConfig.category;
 const legs = props.legs || defaultConfig.legs;
}
```

This way, it's easy to extend the arguments and not worry about argument length mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

```
export const getfilesize = (bytes, decimals = 2) => {
    if (bytes === 0){ 
        return '0 Bytes';
    }else{
        const k = 1024;
        const dm = decimals < 0 ? 0 : decimals;
        const sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
        const i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
        return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];

    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really add anything new to the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_file(file, delete_after = false)
  # code
end
```

Following code may work in this situation including ECMAScript 6 (ES6) as well as earlier versions.

```js
function read_file(file, delete_after) {
    if(delete_after == undefined)
        delete_after = false;//default value

    console.log('delete_after =',delete_after);
}
read_file('text1.txt',true);
read_file('text2.txt');
```

as default value in languages works when the function's parameter value is skipped when calling, in JavaScript it is assigned to **undefined**. This approach doesn't look attractive programmatically but have **backward compatibility**.

Comment: Use `=== undefined`. `==` is broken (`null == undefined` is true, for example). This doesn't add much to existing answers, and JS does support default arguments in recent years, so I'd just recommend that as the best equivalent of the Python code and use a transpiler for backward compatibility. Also, there's a difference between calling the function explicitly with `undefined` and not passing an argument, so I would check the length of the arguments as well if you want true congruence.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes. In fact, there are many languages who support default parameters. Python is one of them:

```
def(a, enter="Hello"):
   print(a+enter)
```

Even though this is Python 3 code due to the parentheses, default parameters in functions also work in JS.

For example, and in your case:

```js
function read_file(file, deleteAfter=false){
  console.log(deleteAfter);
}

read_file("test.txt");
```

But sometimes you don't really need default parameters.

You can just define the variable right after the start of the function, like this:

```js
function read_file(file){
  var deleteAfter = false;
  console.log(deleteAfter);
}

read_file("test.txt");
```

In both of my examples, it returns the same thing. But sometimes they actually could be useful, like in very advanced projects.

So, in conclusion, default parameter values can be used in JS. But it is almost the same thing as defining a variable right after the start of the function. However, sometimes they are still very useful. As you have may noticed, default parameter values take 1 less line of code than the standard way which is defining the parameter right after the start of the function.

***EDIT:*** And this is super important! This will *not* work in IE. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility). So with IE you have to use the "define variable at top of function" method. Default parameters won't work in IE.

Comment: The Python code here isn't valid and the JS code doesn't make much sense. The one with the variable in the function is different than the default value one, because the caller can't actually override the `false` value. So I'm not sure how any of this is relevant.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, This will work in Javascript. You can also do that:

```
function func(a=10,b=20)
{
    alert (a+' and '+b);
}

func(); // Result: 10 and 20

func(12); // Result: 12 and 20

func(22,25); // Result: 22 and 25
```

Comment: It is not currently portable... IE... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility

(And it is a duplicate answer...)