# Javascript: use either a variable, or if it's undefined, a default string

Tags: javascript, function, variables, undefined

I have this code:

```
var phrase = function (variable, defaultPhrase) {
    if (typeof variable === "undefined") {
        return defaultPhrase;
    }
    else {
        return variable;
    }
}
```

It's called like this:

```
Ext.Msg.show({title: phrase(js_shutdown,'Shutdown'), //...
```

What I want to do is to use a default phrase when the variable is not defined, but when I pass an undefined variable to `phrase()`, JS throws an undefined variable error. How do I fix this? Any other ideas to do this?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/how-do-i-make-a-default-value-for-a-parameter-to-a-javascript-function

Comment: What browser(s) is/are showing this problem? See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CBG2f/), which works in FF10 for me just fine.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You don't need a function. The `||` operator is usually used:

```
Ext.Msg.show({ title: js_shutdown || 'Shutdown', //...
```

You can see `||` as:

```
someValue || defaultValue
```

For strings, `defaultValue` is used if `someValue === ""`.

If the variable is not defined at all, you'll need to inline the `typeof x === "undefined"` check, because you cannot pass the variable to a function (that's a `ReferenceError`).

Comment: Wrong. if someValue = 0 instead of being undefined, defaultValue will be used.

Answer (score 15):

Usually using `||` is enough, like others have suggested. However, if you want to have 0, false and null as acceptable values, then you indeed need to check if the type of the variable is undefined. You can use the ternary operator to make it a one-liner:

```
var variable;
var defaultPhrase = "Default";
var phrase = (typeof variable === "undefined" ? defaultPhrase : variable);
console.log(phrase);
// => "Default"
```

Answer (score 4):

In javascript, you typically use the OR operator `||` to provide an alternative value when a variable is undefined:

```
return variable || defaultPhrase || ''
```

In case `variable` is undefined, it will evaluate to false then the second part of the test will be evaluated, if it is also undefined, you can still return an empty string.

Comment: No, `null` and `0` also fall through with this operator.

Answer (score 4):

It's a javascript error to reference an undefined variable with no scope in your function call.  So, if the variable `js_shutdown` doesn't exist in scope, then this:

```
Ext.Msg.show({title: phrase(js_shutdown,'Shutdown'), //...
```

is an error.

For example, this code causes an error on the line that calls the `phrase()` function:

```
var Ext = {};
Ext.Msg = {};
Ext.Msg.show = function() {console.log("success")};

function phrase(variable, defaultPhrase) {
    return(variable || defaultPhrase);
}

Ext.Msg.show({title: phrase(js_shutdown,'Shutdown')});​
```

because the javascript engine isn't able to find js_shutdown in any scope.

But, this is OK:

```
var Ext = {};
Ext.Msg = {};
Ext.Msg.show = function() {console.log("success")};

function phrase(variable, defaultPhrase) {
    return(variable || defaultPhrase);
}

Ext.Msg.show({title: phrase(window.js_shutdown,'Shutdown')});​
```

You can see that this works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JFz6R/

Because you've told the JS engine exactly where to look for js_shutdown and when it isn't there, it just passes undefined to the phrase function (as you want).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

```
 var phrase = variable || defaultPhrase;
```

Or inline:

```
Ext.Msg.show({title: (js_shutdown || 'Shutdown')), //...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would usually code this like `title: js_shutdown || 'Shutdown'` in the absence of possible security issues.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
var phrase = function (variable, defaultPhrase){
    if(variable == undefined){
        return defaultPhrase;
    }else{
        return variable;
    }
}
```