# pre-defined parameters

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to do this in JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(one, two = 1) {
     // code
}

myFunction("foo", "2");

myFunction("bar");
```

I tried this and it doesn't work. I don't know how to call this type of parameters, could somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Answers involving the `two = two || x;` pattern should be understood as risky, depending on your situation.  It means to override *any* "falsy" value of the parameter with the default value, which may or may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function foo(a, b)
 {
   a = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : 42;
   b = typeof b !== 'undefined' ? b : 'default_b';
   //...
 }
```

Possibly duplicate of [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Comment: definite duplicate...but you *do* want to check explicitly for undefined as in this answer

Comment: Because `typeof` returns the type of the parameter you gave.. if `a` is a string then `string` is returned and if there is no parameter then the typeof will return `undefined`

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate, you should vote to close or flag it as such. Don't copy the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

```
function myFunction(one, two) {
     two = two || 1
}
```

To be more precise e.g. it may not work when two is zero, check for null or undefined e.g.

```
if (typeof two === "undefined") two = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
function myFunction(one, two) {
   if (typeof two == 'undefined') two = 1;
   ...
}
```

Beware not to do the common mistake

```
two = two || 1;
```

because this wouldn't allow you to provide `""` or `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ( typeof two === "undefined" ) two = 2;
```

or

```
two = typeof two !== "undefined" ? two : 2;
```

Undefined arguments will have the value `undefined`, which is a "falsy" value. We can test this falsyness, and change the value accordingly.