# Default vars in a method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my method:

```
p.show = function(message, status, timer){

    //do stuff
};
```

Is there a way, so that if vars such as timer are not passed in, to have a default for them, e.g, true.

In php I would do it like:

```
private function show(message, status, timer = true){
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function

Does it work for you?

Comment: @hjpotter92 `|` is a bitwise operator... this is completely different to the `||` logical or.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the logical equivalent is to test the length of the `arguments` array-like object:

```
p.show = function(message, status, timer){
    if (arguments.length < 3 )
        timer = 1000; // default value
    //do stuff
};
```

If you want to set it to the default value even if it's manually passed in, but `undefined` is passed in for the value, you can also use:

```
p.show = function(message, status, timer){
    if (timer === undefined)
        timer = 1000;
    //do stuff
};
```

A more common way is to just use `timer = timer || 1000;` which will set timer to `1000` if it has a falsy value to begin with, so if someone passes in no third argument, or if they pass in `0`, it will still be set to `1000`, but if they pass in a truthy value like `50` or an object, it will keep that value.

In future versions of Javascript (ES6), you will be able to use default arguments the way you are used to from PHP:

```
p.show = function(message, status, timer = 1000){
    //do stuff
};
```

Answer (score 2):

No. This must be done manually:

```
p.show = function(message, status, timer) {
    if( timer === undefined) timer = true;
}
```

If your function does not expect falsy values, you can also do this:

```
timer = timer || true;
// this is commonly seen in event handlers as e = e || window.event;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p.show = function(message, status, timer){
    timer = (timer !== undefined && timer !== null) ? timer : 60;
};
```

Comment: What if `timer` is zero?

Comment: you are correct, the question wasn't very specific about the range of timer values.

See Edit. Thanks @Niet