# Javascript shorthand OR operation

Tags: javascript

I have feeling this must be a duplicate, but I've been unable to find anything, probably due to different wording, or just because there really is nothing better.

I am generating kind of huge chunk of JS code, which "ORs" object properties with variables, while identifiers don't necessarily match. It looks like this (values are boolean):

```
a.borderline = a.borderline || borderline;
a.st1 = a.st1 || st;
a.ref64 = a.ref64 || ref;
a.unfortunatelySometimesQuiteLongIndentifier123 = a.unfortunatelySometimesQuiteLongIndentifier123 || unfortunatelySometimesQuiteLongIndentifier;
...
```

To make it leaner I tried something like

```
a.st1 |= st;
```

but it makes `a.st1` integer instead of boolean and I don't want to add another line with double negation to retype it back to boolean.

Using intuition I also tried `||=`, which did not help :)

Is there any better (shorter) way of writing these commands?

**Note:** I cannot process the commands using a loop, because the commands are not executed all at once, instead they are spread in small chunks in the rest of the code (which was omitted for simplicity).

Comment: In Javascript, no, not that I know of. You may want to look into coffeescript, which has a `?=`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why `1` and `0` are objectionable?

Comment: @PatrickQ Later I am making JSON out of it and sending it somewhere. To comply with the protocol I have to distinguish between `0` and `false`. Yet I cannot convert all zeroes to `false`, as there are also valid numeric values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no shorthand OR operator in javascript. [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) however does provide `||=` and `?=` to support [this idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function).

> Is there any better (shorter) way of writing these commands?

In your case, you're amending the `a` object instead of assigning to variables. You might do this in a loop fashion:

```
function amendWith(target, source)
    for (var p in source)
        if (!target[p])
            target[p] = source[p];
    return target;
}
```

```
amendWith(a, {
    borderline: borderline,
    st1: st,
    ref64: ref,
    unfortunatelySometimesQuiteLongIndentifier123: unfortunatelySometimesQuiteLongIndentifier
    …
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use the loop (added the **Note** after you had probably read the question), but I'll definitely investigate Coffeescript option. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice the edit. You might however post your full code (either in a new question at [cr.SE], in some paste service online, or into your question) so that we can see whether there is a better pattern then.

Comment: OK, cool! Coffeescript will work for me. Luckily, it can be compiled into the "long" code after passing the bottleneck, so CS saves the day. Btw interestingly, the `a.st1 ||= st` is compiled into `a.st1 || (a.st1 = st);`, which took me a while to understand, but well.. it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is any shorter, but just as an alternative idea you could put the OR logic in a function and then loop through your values.

```
function myFunctionName(value1, value2) {
  return value1 || value2;
}

//names are property names of object 'a' that you want to set, values are the alternate (default) values
var myMapping = {borderline:borderline, st1:st, reallyLongName123:reallyLongName}; 

for (temp in myMapping) {
  a.temp = myFunctionName(a[temp], myMapping[temp]);
}
```

Since your unable to use a loop and you don't know all the values ahead of time, you could try adding the function to your object 'a'

```
a.test = function(propName, otherValue) {
  this[propName] = this[propName] || otherValue;
};

a.test("borderline", borderline);
```

Comment: Not shorter since you're *still* repeating `a.borderline` twice.

Comment: Exactly, the main problem is repeating of the `a.borderline` part, which can sometimes be very long.

Comment: @Erlik I updated the code to use a loop, does that make it any cleaner?

Comment: @monkybonk05 Yes, now it's not repeated. However, I cannot use loop, neither the static initialization `var myMapping = {...`. I am obtaining the values in a scattered way as well as using them (see the **Note** later added to my question).

Comment: @Erlik Are you able to add functions to object 'a'? If so, check out my update.

Comment: @monkybonk05 That's actually very interesting and yet so simple. `a` is not the only object changed this way, but I can modify it to `test = function(a, propName, otherValue) {...` Thanks! +1