# How can I make Javascript parameters default to something if not present?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
this.checkButton = function (buttonName, element, expectedPresent, expectedEnabled) {
    var enabledCheck = expectedEnabled ? "enabled" : "disabled";
    it('Find a ' + buttonName + ' button and check it is ' + enabledCheck, function () {
        expect(element.isPresent()).toBe(expectedPresent);
        expect(element.isEnabled()).toBe(expectedEnabled);
    });
}
```

Is there a way I can make this so that if the function is called without the last two parameters then those parameters will both default to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want.

Try to say in starting of function.

```
expectedPresent = (expectedPresent==undefined) ? true : expectedPresent;
expectedEnabled = (expectedEnabled==undefined) ? true : expectedEnabled;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That doesn't work. At all.

Comment: This way it's not possible to pass `expectedPresent` as `false`.

Comment: use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: @Barmar sorry for asking, but how does that help?

Comment: Never mind, I was wrong.

Comment: ok thank you all of you for your suggestions

Comment: @Robby / Others - Do you think this is a good solution now ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/894877/3558960

Answer (score 2):

Compare the parameters to `undefined` to know if they are present:

```
    this.checkButton = function (buttonName, element, expectedPresent, expectedEnabled) {

        if(expectedPresent === undefined) {
            expectedPresent = true;
        }
        if(expectedEnabled === undefined) {
            expectedEnabled = true;
        }
        var enabledCheck = expectedEnabled ? "enabled" : "disabled";
        it('Find a ' + buttonName + ' button and check it is ' + enabledCheck, function () {
            expect(element.isPresent()).toBe(expectedPresent);
            expect(element.isEnabled()).toBe(expectedEnabled);
        });
    }
```