# parameter in function even not isset ,still work

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible call a function, whatever the parameter isset or not,
how to do it?

```
select();
select($response_message);

function select($response_message) {
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP, when you declare the function, put in a default value

```
function select($response_message = 'whatever') {
    ....
}
```

At this point, `select()` and `select('whatever')` run the same thing.

[for more information on PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

As for javascript, [that process is a little more involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Comment: Thanks for reply, in php what if the $response_message sometime is an array,  can I define it before function like,  $response_message = array(...);  function select($response_message = $response_message') {

Comment: If you need to pass in an array, you can just run it like you'd expect `select(array('foo', 'bar'))`. 'whatever' is only assigned if you leave out the argument when you call it.

Comment: As for attempting to assign a default value like that, you'll need to do all that inside the function declaration itself, cant do `function select($this = $that) {}`.

Comment: so is it means  I set function select($a = 'default') {}   and other side I can call function like select()  or   $a = 'custom' select($a)