# This code is not running is google chrome, get syntax error in function definition

Tags: drupal, yii, continuous-integration

```
function validateThisField(fieldID,fieldType="text"){

//var ID=fieldID.substr(fieldID.length - 1);

//var fieldSubName = fieldID.slice(0, -1);
var fieldVal = jQuery('#'+fieldID).val();
if(fieldType=="text" && fieldVal.length > 0){
    jQuery('#'+fieldID+'_lbl').addClass('errlabel');
    jQuery('#'+fieldID).removeClass('associate_error_border_radius');
}else{
    jQuery('#'+fieldID+'_lbl').removeClass('errlabel');
    jQuery('#'+fieldID).addClass('associate_error_border_radius');
```

`This is html`

```
`<input class="associate_error_border_radius" onblur="validateThisField('assoc_firstname_1');" name="assoc_firstname_1" id="assoc_firstname_1" type="textbox">`
```

This code is running in Mozilla but in google chrome get syntax error in function definition.

Comment: It would help if you tell us what the syntax error is, instead of asking us to guess.

Comment: This is syntax error in Google chrome: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use default parameters in javascript use something like this:

```
function foo(param){
    //'default' is the default value
    if(typeof param === 'undefined'){ param = 'default'; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have default parameters in Javascript so you need to remove the '="text"' in your function definition

```
function validateThisField(fieldID,fieldType="text"){
```

to

```
function validateThisField(fieldID,fieldType){
```

See this SO post for more information [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)