# Ionic transitions getting white page only in ios

Tags: html, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Im developing an app in ionic and its working perfectly fine in android, emulators and web (with ionic serve). But when is running in ios devices in transitions between pages suddenly it shows a white view instead the view that it have to display. This doesn't happen all time and i didn't figured out when specifically happen.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolve it, it was a problem with transitions of ionic in ios. Adding this line to config in app.js like this

```
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) { 
        $ionicConfigProvider.views.swipeBackEnabled(false);
    }
```

Disable all back navigations transitions with swipe.

Comment: I think this has fixed it for me too. Thank you very much @Matias Araya!

Answer (score 2):

it is probably a javascript error. To find it, the best way is:

1. first connect the phone with your mac (must be a mac) by USB.
2. Open Safary (no Chrome or Firefox)
3. In the Safary settings -> Advanced -> enable develop tools
   [image]
4. Now on Safary will appear a develop menu on the top, click on it and you will see your phone and the app running, click on it.
   [image]
5. In the develop tools, will appear all the console you normally see testing with ionic serve, but in the real device.
6. Just use the app and when you get a black page check the javascript error on safary develop tool.
   [image]

I hope it helps, it did helped me a lot after discover it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i didnt know about this way to debugging in ios!!! Nevertheless this didnt solve my problem, in the console doesnt appear any error when the blank page appears.

Comment: What about the HTML? Did you check it? Maybe it opened a link and navigate to a blank page. An '<a href="">' that get intercepted by javascript been clicked before the interceptor has been registered.

Answer (score 0):

For what I searched, it can be a lot of things.. What helped me to figure out my case was small commits. 
Anyway, I tried to use default param values and it doesn't work for my webview in iOS. If that's your problem too, you can see an alternative way to do default param values here: 
[Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

didn't work:

```
function(param = defaultValue){}
```

did work:

```
function(param){    
  param = param ? param : defaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `can-swipe-back="false"` on your ion-view element.