# White flash when call map.remove() or map.getMap()

Tags: cordova, google-maps, cordova-plugins, phonegap-gmaps-plugin

I'm using the maps plugin (version 1) in the Cordova app: https://github.com/mapsplugin 
When to go to the map page or go the other page from the map page, on the app, there is **a quick white flash**.
It **displaying a white screen and then disappear after about 0.5s**, then the app works normally. 
Perhaps the both map.remove() and map.getMap() function is not work smoothly.
This issue happens on the both android and ios.
I know that **the plugin changes the background-color of the map div and the parent elements as transparent**. After I call the remove function, **it will remove all inline style of map div and parent elements**. This may be the cause. But I don't know how to resolve it.
Please help me resolve it. Thanks.

```
$scope.initNativeMap = function () {
        var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
        // Initialize the map view
        map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);
        map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapReady);
    };

    function onMapReady() {
        console.log("map ready >> find current location");
        mixpanel.track("Map: initiliazed");
        $scope.getLocation();
    };

$scope.changePage = function (pageName) {
       map.remove();
       $state.go(pageName);
    }
```

Comment: The white screen can have different reasons, for instance (transition issues with the framework/ionic)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334960/ionic-transitions-getting-white-page-only-in-ios]. You could also show the splashscreen before removing the map and hide it after the new page is loaded.

Comment: @Blauharley: Thank you, but it is not the cause of my issue. I will try fix it with the splash screen

Comment: Just take note that [`getMap()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases#june_27_2016) function is no longer available in the Google Play services SDK. The `getMap()` function has been deprecated since December 2014. So change your `getMap()` to `getMapAsync()`. For more information, check this [blog post](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/06/marker-zindex-and-more-come-to-google.html).