# Default value for parameter expect function

Tags: javascript, optional-parameters

I want to add default value for function parameter expect to receive a function.

**Look at the following example:**

```
/** 
* @param {function} callback
* @param {String} name
*/
function example(callback, name){
    console.log('Hello' + name + 'from parent function');
    callback();
}


// implementation
example(null, "Mickey");
```

I want to make the `callback` as optional parameter.

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function?rq=1 ?

Comment: I know how to set default value for normal variable, but I don't know for function

Comment: In ES6 we now have the ability to set default parameter values, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: @LionKing In _JavaScript_ there is no difference between a _"normal variable"_ and a _function_

Comment: Functions are objects and are therefore like any other value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you typically test whether the parameter is `null` or `undefined` and provide a default. More succinctly you can use `||`:

```
callback = callback || (some default value);
```

Using `||` is looser because it will also treat anything that's "falsy" in JavaScript as missing, including `false`, an empty string and zero. So it's not useful for optional boolean parameters.

In your case, your default value is a function:

```
function example(opt_callback, name) {
  var callback = opt_callback || function() {};
  console.log('Hello' + name + 'from parent function');
  callback();
}
```

Here the default function provides nothing, but you could add some default behavior to the default function here.

Naming optional arguments with `opt_` is a practice recommended by the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml#Naming) and [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler?hl=en). I think it makes code more readable, but maybe I have just gotten used to it.

Unless there are other overriding readability reasons, it is good to put optional arguments at the end of the parameter list, for example:

```
function example(name, opt_callback) {
  ...
```

That way callers can succinctly call your function with just one argument, for example `example('Mickey')`, because the default value of unspecified arguments in JavaScript is `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

Since a function has a typeof "function", you could do a simple typeof check.  Though JavaScript functions are first-class, so you don't really need to change much.

```
/** 
* @param {function} callback
* @param {String} name
*/
function example(callback, name){
    if (typeof a !== "function") {
      callback = function(){ }; // replace this with your default function
    }
    console.log('Hello' + name + 'from parent function');
    callback();
}
```

For more in-depth answers please consult the protected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function?rq=1)

EDIT:  Just as an aside, it is better practice to make your optional callback the second parameter.  that way you don't have to explicitly pass null to get a default value.

```
function example(name, callback) { ... }

example("hello"); // callback has value null

example("hello", function(){...}); // also valid
```

Comment: A good native no-operation function in _JavaScript_ is [`Function.prototype`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4)

Comment: no, its just a nothing function.  replace it with whatever you like, a better do nothing function is just function( ){ }