# Can we just use "if (a === undefined)" to handle default parameter values in JavaScript before ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, default-parameters

In ES6, we can use

```
function f (x, y = 7, z = 42) {
    return x + y + z
}

console.log(f(1));
```

and both Babel and Traceur translate it to similar ES5 code this way:

```
"use strict";

function f(x) {
    var y = arguments.length <= 1 || arguments[1] === undefined ? 7 : arguments[1];
    var z = arguments.length <= 2 || arguments[2] === undefined ? 42 : arguments[2];

    return x + y + z;
}

console.log(f(1));
```

isn't it true that we can just handle it, as on http://es6-features.org/#DefaultParameterValues by:

```
function f (x, y, z) {
    if (y === undefined)
        y = 7;
    if (z === undefined)
        z = 42;
    return x + y + z;
}
console.log(f(1));
```

even [Mozilla's website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) uses something like:

```
var b = typeof b !== 'undefined' ?  b : 1;
```

or [a standard answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function) uses:

```
function foo(a, b)
 {
   a = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : 42;
   b = typeof b !== 'undefined' ? b : 'default_b';
   ...
 }
```

Why don't we use the short and simple

```
if (y === undefined)
        y = 7;
```

is there any subtle difference?

(It is true in the global scope, we can't just say `a === undefined` if `a` was never declared (it would raise an error). But inside of a function, we can just use `a === undefined` because `a` is listed on the parameter list already. Both Babel and Traceur don't list the default parameter in the parameter list, however.)

Comment: Apologies, I missed the difference between `y === undefined` and `arguments[1]` in the question when marking as a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we just use `if (a === undefined)` to handle default parameter values in JavaScript before ES6?

Yes, you can do that, it's totally fine.

But you are right, there *is* a subtle difference (or two):

- `f.length` is the [ExpectedArgumentCount](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions-static-semantics-expectedargumentcount), that is the number of parameters before the first rest or initialised one.
- In `function f( a=b, b=0 )` the variable `b` has a temporal dead zone and must not be used by the initialiser of `a`.

Transpilers like Babel try to replicate things like these as closely as possible, that's why they use the `arguments` objects and declare the variables in the function body. Btw, Babel fails to handle `function f(a=0, b)` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, that's the way I've always done it(roughly 15 years) and it never gives errors.
By adding it in the parameter list you always have access to it as a declared variable, and i've never encountered a browser that couldn't handle it.

I prefer to use `typeof varname == 'undefined'` though, because I've had some issues with `=== undefined` in some obscure browsers in the past.

I always tend to stay as far away as possible from the arguments property as I can.