# Default Parameters in Function Expressions

Tags: javascript, default-parameters, function-expression

Default parameters in javscript function declerations can be achieved with a simple assignment as follows:

```
function foo(arg1 = 'default1', arg2 = 'default2') { ... }
```

But how can I have default parameters for function expressions, as the following does NOT work in chrome v47:

```
var foo = function (arg1 = 'default1', arg2 = 'default2') { ... }
```

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Your second piece of code works. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: Babel transpiles both without problems.

Comment: Huh!? Then why am I getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =" error in the browser console?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Default values for function arguments are an ES2015 thing.

Comment: Chrome has not implemented this yet. Try it in a Firefox console.

Comment: I am NOT going to change my browser to have this work. I would much rather change the syntax!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function

Comment: So do so using non-ES6 JS; not sure what the problem is. Your question was very specific, asking about default parameters in function expressions--by definition that makes it ES6-specific. If your question is actually "how do I do this without ES6 you might want to change the question to reflect that.

Comment: If you want to use that syntax in ES5, use this: https://babeljs.io/

Comment: @DaveNewton I am confused. Function Expressions are ES5... so how is my question ES6-specific?

Comment: `function (arg1 = 'default1', arg2 = 'default2'){}` is ES2015 syntax

Comment: I guess I am gonna have to do more reading up on the version specifics. Anyway, thank you everybody.

Comment: @Grateful Function expressions are much older than ES5. Default parameters are ES6.

Comment: Again, thank you for the clarifications.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this in javascript:

```
function foo(arg1 = 'default1', arg2 = 'default2') { ; }
```

See in your console, it gives syntax error. You can do this:

```
function foo(arg1, arg2) {
   if ("undefined" == typeof arg2) {
       arg2 = "default2";
   }
}

var foo2 = function(arg1, arg2) {
   if ("undefined" == typeof arg2) {
       arg2 = "default2";
   }
}
```

Comment: You're not using an ES2015 browser apparently.

Comment: I have Chrome 48. Besides the question was tagged with javascript

Comment: @Pointy Is chrome not qualified?

Comment: Chrome may not default to supporting it.

Comment: The MDN compatibility table says it's in Chrome 49.

Comment: You most certainly *can* do this in JavaScript, it depends on which *version* you're using.

Comment: Sorry, I mean an alternative syntax. I think your suggestion above should work. Thanks.