# default parameters in node.js

Tags: node.js, parameters, callback, default

How does one go about setting default parameters in node.js?

For instance, let's say I have a function that would normally look like this:

```
function(anInt, aString, cb, aBool=true){
   if(bool){...;}else{...;}
   cb();
}
```

To call it would look something like this:

```
function(1, 'no', function(){
  ...
}, false);
```

or:

```
function(2, 'yes', function(){
  ...
});
```

However, it doesn't seem that node.js supports default parameters in this manner.  What is the best way to acomplish above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function

Comment: you could use babel and keep your original code.

Comment: Just a side node that 'no' and 'yes' aren't good types to use if you have something that is true or false - use a Boolean!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simplest solution is to say inside the function

```
var variable1 = typeof variable1  !== 'undefined' ?  variable1  : default_value;
```

So this way, if user did not supply variable1, you replace it with default value.

In your case:

```
function(anInt, aString, cb, aBool) {
  aBool = typeof aBool  !== 'undefined' ? aBool : true;
  if(bool){...;}else{...;}
  cb();
}
```

Answer (score 81):

**2017 answer: node 6 and above include ES6 default parameters**

```
var sayMessage = function(message='This is a default message.') {
  console.log(message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See the [github issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3070). You can enable default parameters in current node versions (f.ex. 5.8.0) by using `--harmony_default_parameters`

> ```
> node --harmony_default_parameters --eval "const t = function(i = 42) { return i }; console.log(t());"
> ```

[...]

> It'll be enabled by default in v6.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a new function that already has a set of arguments passed into it:

```
fn1 = fn.bind(fn, 1, 'no', function(){}, false);
fn1();
fn2 = fn.bind(fn, 2, 'yes', function(){});
fn2(true);
```

Alternatively, langues like [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) that compile into JavaScript provide mechanisms that support default parameters without having to use `bind`:

```
CoffeeScript:

fn = (bar='foo') ->
```

---

```
JavaScript:

fn = function(bar) {
  if (bar == null) {
    bar = 'foo';
  }
};
```