# Manage construction of javascript call when 2nd parameter is null?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a javascript call in `OnClientClick` that looks like the following:

```
OnClientClick='<%# "return DisplayAlert(" + Eval("BedNum") + "," + Eval("ClientId") + ");" %>'
```

But when `ClientId` is *null*, the function call is constructed incorrectly with error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` since the function call produces `return DisplayAlert(value, );`

Is there a way to avoid this error when the 2nd parameter is `null`?

Thanks

Comment: How in the world is that a duplicate? You're suggesting adding `ToString().Length`?

Comment: It is not a duplicate that asks/answers **exactly the same** question. But it is a duplicate that needs to solve basically **the same problem** - to Eval or not to Eval something conditionally (in your case comma+second argument). So it at least should give you some ideas.

Comment: You're right and I apologize. I did, and I ended up using something like this: `OnClientClick='<%# "return ShowRoom(" + Eval("BedNum") + "," + Eval("ClientId").ToString().Length + ");" %>'`

Comment: That way, if 2nd parameter is `null` then I get 0. Otherwise, I get a positive value. Thanks again.

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function fix your problem right way ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, all you would need to do is check its value, and for `null` have a default value of your choosing, or the original `clientId` in the case that it isn't null.

Something like this:

```
ClientId == null ? "whateverDefaultValueYouWant" : clientId
```

Comment: the issue isn't the javascript function. The problem is the call when 2nd value is `null`.