# How do you make some parameters of Meteor Methods optional?

Tags: meteor

I want to write a Method to update a document. The client calling the Method may not want to update all fields exposed by the Method via its parameters. What is the right way to implement this in Meteor?

Comment: why would that be any different from optional parameters in any other javascript function?

Comment: Thanks. That answered my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can add some optional arguments to a javascript method:

```
function updateDocument(requiredArg, optionalArg){
  // optionally set the contents of your optional argument to a default
  optionalArg = (typeof optionalArg === 'undefined') ? 'default' : optionalArg;

  //update your document

}
```

An other way of passing (multiple) arguments is to put them in an object:

```
var myDocument = Documents.find({foo: 'bar'})
var myUpdatedFields = {
  field1: 'test',
  field5: 'option',
  field6: 'etc. etc.'
}

updateDocument(myDocument._id, myUpdatedFields);
```

This calls the updateDocument method with a required argument (the document id) and a set of fields that needs to be updated.