# Why PhpStorm is highlighting this as error in my JavaScript declaration

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

I've declared this JS function and PhpStorm is highlighting it as an error, saying that `,or) expected`.

```
function getData(params, toCache=true) { ...
```

[image]

Why is PhpStorm highlighting `toCache=true` as an error?  Is this not the correct way to [declare default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) params in JavaScript?  My code is working, so is this just a bug in PhpStorm.

Comment: Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > select "ECMAScript6" from dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because `default parameters` are part of ES6 specification and your project environment is set to ES5.

Comment: that's it exactly, found an answer for it here too http://stackoverflow.com/a/37571826/1814446 - if I could I would down vote myself

Answer (score 1):

Probably, You set PhpStorm to ES5 where default parameters work differently. Example of default parameters for ES5:

```
function getData(params, toCache){
   if (typeof(toCache)==='undefined') toCache = true;
}
```

Your code is written on the ES6 and running, PhpStorm highlights.