# Pass default parameter values in function react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got this error after updating react-native and react

I think this is right syntax, but I don't know why this error is shown:

```
 this.list = function(table, callback, wheredata = [],selection = '',extra = '') {
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
>   at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
>   at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
>   at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
>   at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
>   at Object. (/Users/apcrat/Documents/redux/delfoo_React/api/model/catalog/cuisine_route.js:7:12)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)

Comment: may be something wrong with `this.list =` ?

Comment: You are going to need to give more context.. Are you using that in a `class`?

Comment: you cannot set default value for argument in Ecmascript 5. you can set `wheredata = wheredata || [];` inside your function

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile your code with [Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/) to use [Ecmascript 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) features or if you want to work on es5, you can do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Comment: I am tried to work on React-native. and i am using this to create API.and i am also using babel.js and ES5