# Data object extension leap year javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code so far:

```
/*function isSchrikkeljaar(year) {
    year = 2016;
    if (//is empty(year)) {
       //use current year
    }
    if (year%4===0 && (year%100!=0 || year%400===0)) {
       return true;
       console.log(true);
    } else {
       return false;
        console.log(false);
    }
}*/
```

If the year is a leap year it logs true, if not it should log false, if the year is empty it should take the current year.
Can anyone help me out, been stuck for a while.
The problem is that I don't know how to give it the current year when the year is empty.

Comment: Remove the year=2016. do year=year||2016 , this will take 2016 if isSchrikkeljaar

Comment: If the logs are not showing, move the `log` statement above `return` otherwise those will not execute.

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/894860/218196) ... please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: [`var isLeapYear = (year = new Date().getFullYear()) => year % 4 === 0 && (year % 100 !== 0 || year % 400 === 0);`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/3gkur20j/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function isSchrikkeljaar(year) { 
    year = year||new Date().getFullYear();
    if (year%4===0 && (year%100!=0 || year%400===0)) { 
       return true; 
    } else { 
       return false;
    } 
 }
```

If year is set take year as year, if not take the actual date and get its year.

Use cases:

```
isSchrikkelyear();//2017 = false
isSchrikkelyear(2016); //false
```