# How to pass a opitional array as parameter in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, parameters

I want to create a function in Javascript that has an optional array as parameter.

I was following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)  but it not solved my question.

The function should be like this:

```
function myname (par1, par2, par3=[]){
//some script
}
```

or like this?

```
function myname (par1, par2, par3=false){
//some script
}
```

Any help?

Note: par3 is a parameter and must be an array if any.

In other words,

I would like a function in javascript similar to this one in php:

```
function myname ($par1,$par2, array $par3=NULL){
// some code        
}
```

Comment: This depends entirely on what your function is doing. If it is expecting `par3` to be an array, then the former.

Comment: specifically what did you have a problem with the other post.

Comment: If you use your first example, `par3` will always be an empty array if you don't define it.  In your second example `par3` will always be false if you don't define it.

Comment: @DanielA.White, the post show `delete_after = false`. That not works for me because my 3th parameter must be an array (=[]) AND must be false (=false)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `function`   and not `funtion`. There is typo mistake in your code.

```
function myname (par1, par2, par3=[]){
//some script
};
```

Comment: Hi Agalo it was a typo error. But this is not the issue. In your answer if I call myname(3,4) will be working ?

Comment: Yes, it will work.

Comment: I just tested.  It is not working as expected. It calls myname(2,3); or myname(2,3,7); It should not work in the second scenario becaus p3 must be an array

Comment: Javascript is a dynamic language and you can change the type of a property. This is a language feature. But, you can check if the passed parameter is not an array and then ignore that parameter. `Array.isArray(param3)`

Comment: Ok I was trying to avoid check. If there is no way, Must to be checked. I made an update to compare with php.