# Sanity check for default args in vanilla javascript function

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Keeping things simple here, consider this modern vanilla JS code:

```
function foo(bar, baz=1){
    ...
```

The use of default arg settings (baz) is pretty simple and expected. [Mozilla says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) not a problem. Is there something in best practice regarding default params in JS I never learned in the 15+ years?

My IDE (JetBrains) can not hang with the code, yet my apps are working fine.  Is there a reason why this is throwing errors or is my IDE in error? See screen shot of the validation error.

[image]

and Firefox Dev is fine with the syntax:

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps change `JavaScript language version` to match one that supports it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/javascript.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ES6 this is completely fine. See [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function).

May be you need to say JetBrain that you are using ES6, this is working only in your browsers that support some subset of ES6. Check the compatibility list.

Comment: This app is very much ES6 thankfully. As a Python guy my skin crawls when I have to do JS work.