# Canvas default settings to enable user input

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am building a IMG crop/re-size/zoom tool and I want to be able to pass some default parameters into the drawImage() function in case some are not defined yet.

For example:

I get a re-size request and can therefor input width and height:

```
drawImage(this.loadedImg,0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,this.imageWidth, this.imageHeight);
```

I cant find the defaults anywhere. I tried false and 0, but neighter worked.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: More generally, are you looking for default function parameter? You can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I got clearly what you are after, So I'll assume you want the default values for the arguments of `drawImage(source, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)` when you use the short version `drawImage(source, dx, dy)` or the less short `drawImage(source, dx, dy, dw, dh)`.

In case of an `<img>` element as source, it is `drawImage(img, 0,0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight)`.

In case of a `<video>` element as source, it is `drawImage(vid, 0,0, vid.videoWidth, vid.videoHeight, dx, dy, vid.videoWidth, vid.videoHeight)`.

For any other source type it is `drawImage(source, 0, 0, source.width, source.height, 0, 0, dx, dy)`.

So we can make this table :

```
drawImage(
   source: always inputed,
   sx: input || 0,
   sy: input || 0,
   sw: input || source.[natural | video]width,
   sh: input || source.[natural | video]height,
   dx: always inputed,
   dy: always inputed,
   dw: input || sw,
   dh: input || sh
)
```

Comment: This is what I was after, sory for my late response and aknowledgment of your correct answer, I resolved this problem by myselfe yesterday afterall. But the table idea is appreciated.