# How to check whether a function was called on blur or on focus?

Tags: jquery

How can I check whether `my_func` was called from `blur` or `focus`, in the following code?

```
function my_func(my_arg) {
    // Maintain compatibility with ECMAScript < 6
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/894877/1563422
    my_arg = typeof my_arg !== 'undefined' ? my_arg : false;

    if(my_arg) {
        // do something
    }
}

// Apply to both blur and focus, in case a user clicks from a field
// onto the background of the page, without focusing another field first
$('#appform').on({
    'blur' : my_func,
    'focus': my_func
}, 'input, select');
```

Comment: You can see the type if you just console the `my_arg`

Comment: And if you just console it, you can see the type as a node in the object with your given code assuming `invalid_style` is `my_func`

Comment: @Huangism Sorry, I've corrected that, you're right they're the same function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event object's `type` field will contain a name for the event that triggered it (though not always the same one you defined for the handler; `blur` becomes `focusout` for example):

> The Event.type read-only property returns a string containing the event's type. It is set when the event is constructed and is the name commonly used to refer to the specific event, such as click, load, or error

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type

```js
function my_func(my_arg) {
  console.log(my_arg.type);
}

$('#appform').on({
    'blur' : my_func,
    'focus': my_func
}, 'input, select');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="appform">
<input>
<input>
<select><option>a</option><option>b</option></select>
```

Comment: Isn't the event always passed to the handler?

Comment: You're right; thanks for pointing that out. I corrected that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get away with passing a bound function as the event handler.

```
$('#appform').on({
    'blur' : invalid_style.bind(null, 'from-blur'),
    'focus': invalid_style.bind(null, 'from-focus')
}, 'input, select');
```

The `bind` call returns a function object with some parameters already "bound" to it. In my example, we are passing a `null` as the context and then a string as the first argument to the `invalid_style` function.

Within your function, you will now be able to inspect the `my_arg` argument and decipher from where your function was called.

---

Reference: [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)