# Elif me this example from Exploring ES6 please

Tags: javascript

Excerpt from the book: "The default value is computed on demand, only when it is actually needed:

```
const log = console.log.bind(console);

function g(x=log('x'), y=log('y')) {return 'DONE'}
```

Why when I give one actual parameter to this function it gives return of y, when two arguments it just returns 'DONE', but if I don;t give it any act. parameters it will yield x, y and return statement?

```
>> g(0)
y
"DONE"

>> g()
x
y
'DONE'

>> g(1)
y
'DONE'

g(1, 2)
'DONE'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you are setting to `x` and `y` in your function are `default` values. That means if you do not pass any parameters to function `g`, it will use the values you set as default `x = log('x') and y = log('y')`.

`g(0)` is the same as `g(x = 0, y = log('y'))` so only `y` gets logged out. You do nothing with `0` inside your function, so only `DONE` is returned.

`g()` is the same as `g(x = log('x'), y = log('y'))` so both `x` and `y` get logged out.

`g(1)` is the same as the first example: `g(x = 1, y = log('y'))` so only `y` gets logged out. You do nothing with `1` inside your function, so only `DONE` is returned.

`g(1, 2)` is the same as `g(x = 1, y = 2)` so nothing gets logged out because you do nothing with `1 and 2` inside your function. Only `DONE` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

This function declaration says:

```
function g(x=log('x'), y=log('y')) {return 'DONE'}
```

if no `x` is passed in, then compute `log(x)` which is just `console.log(x)` (this causes `"x" to be written to the console)`; if no `y` is passed in compute `log(y)`.

If you pass in `x` or `y` then there is no need to compute the values, so `log(x)` (or y) is not computed and you get no console log. If you don't pass in the values, then it calls `log()` which write the value to the console. Regardless of what you pass in the return value of the function is `DONE`.

It's a pretty artificial example, but it looks like the point is to demonstrate that if you pass in a value, the right side of the equals is never evaluated.