# Use of setting null in function

Tags: javascript

I was following a tutorial online and they set the predefined value of the function as null(`data` and `details`), what is the use of the null, what does it mean

```
onClick={(data, details = null) => {
        console.log(data.description, details);
      }}
```

Comment: it acts as optional parameter!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is a false-evaluated ("falsey") JavaScript object type whereas an empty object (like one defined via `{}`) is a true-evaluated ("truthy") object.

In many situations I have seen, developers will use it to signify the parameter is expecting an object because `typeof null === "object"`. Without the `details = null`, a missing details parameter would be `undefined`, a type all of its own (`typeof undefined === "undefined"`).

Answer (score 2):

I think you know what is the notation of putting null in parameters and [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function) explains it further.

There are usages of putting default value to null.

1. You can easily check whether values are assigned with lesser code. ex: `if(details){}`
2. You can directly send that to database as a null value.
3. You may do not prefer default `undefined` value based on your application requirements

Hope this helps.