# How to fix problem with arguments in function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I have a function ,that i'm using in  multiple components . It collects data  from components and stores it in db. My problem is that function has a lot of arguments and some of them might not be used in some components . Take a look :

```
export default async function addUserLogs(account, service, terminal,isSaved,isSentToGateway,amount ) {
  const obj = {
    serviceID: service,
    terminalID: terminal,
    amountName: account,
    amount: amount,
    isSaved: isSaved,
    isSentToGateway: isSentToGateway,
  };

  const db = await InitDb();
  const tx = db.transaction('userLogs', 'readwrite');
  const store = tx.objectStore('userLogs');
  const index = await store.put(obj);
  let params = {};
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('params') !== null) {
    params = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('params'));
  }
  window.localStorage.setItem(
    'params',
    JSON.stringify({ ...params, userLogIndex: index })
  );
}
```

For example  account and service arguments  i'm passing to function in on one component, others arguments is not required . In another component I only need to pass amount argument, but I need to specify previous arguments to do not overwrite other values. But there is an error  "account, service, terminal,isSaved,isSentToGateway is not defined". Could you please suggest me how to fix that problem

Comment: in JS arguments are optional, so there is nothing you need to do except make a condition inside your function `if (arg1) { do something }` etc.

Comment: Because you access it when creating the `obj` and did not pass it,  that is why you get the error. You should make the ones that are not mandatory have default values so that when you don't provide them there won't be any problem

Comment: I think you should refer it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function

Comment: I think you should refer it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 1):

addUserLogs can receive an object with optional keys and merge the last received object with the new one:

```
export default async function addUserLogs(newParams) {
  const lastParams = <get the last params from storage>;
  const obj = Object.assign(lastParams, newParams);
  ...
} 

// usage examples
addUserLogs({amountName: 'x', serviceID: 1, terminalID: 2, isSaved: true ,isSentToGateway: false, amount: 10});
addUserLogs({isSentToGateway: false, amount: 10});
addUserLogs({amountName: 'x', serviceID: 1, terminalID: 2});
```

If you want to be more declarative about addUserLogs signature you can do something link:

```
export default async function addUserLogs({amountName, serviceID, terminalID, isSaved ,isSentToGateway, amount}) {
  const lastParams = <get the last params from storage>;
  const newParams = {
      amountName: amountName || lastParams.amountName, 
      serviceID: serviceID || lastParams.serviceID, 
      terminalID: terminalID || lastParams.terminalID, 
      isSaved: isSaved === undefined ? lastParams.isSaved : isSaved,
      isSentToGateway: isSentToGateway === undefined ? lastParams.isSentToGateway : isSentToGateway, 
      amount: amount === undefined ? lastParams.amount : amount
  };
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get ride of this and make your function more generic, You should provide default arguments to the function so that when you don't pass any the oject creation here

```
   serviceID: service,
   terminalID: terminal,
   amountName: account,
   amount: amount,
   isSaved: isSaved,
   isSentToGateway: isSentToGateway,
 };
```

will not break. To do that you use the below format

```
export default async function addUserLogs(account="default", service = "default", terminal = "default value",isSaved = "default value",isSentToGateway = "default value",amount = "default Value" )
```

provide default only for variables that are not going to be required in other places when called.

Note when you call this function and provide params they will replace the default but when you don't the function will use the default as such your function doesn't break with undefined variables

Answer (score 0):

in that example you can set null for some arguments that is not required and you don't want to use them when callig your function.

you can use some filters for your arguments like so:

````
export default async function addUserLogs(account, service, terminal,isSaved,isSentToGateway,amount ) {
  const obj = {};

  if(account) obj.amountName = account;
  if(service) obj.serviceID = service;
  if(terminal) obj.terminalID = terminal;
  if(isSaved !== null) obj.isSaved = isSaved;
  if(isSentToGateway !== null) obj.isSentToGateway = isSentToGateway;
  if(amount) obj.amount = amount;

  const db = await InitDb();
  const tx = db.transaction('userLogs', 'readwrite');
  const store = tx.objectStore('userLogs');
  const index = await store.put(obj);
  let params = {};
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('params') !== null) {
    params = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('params'));
  }
  window.localStorage.setItem(
    'params',
    JSON.stringify({ ...params, userLogIndex: index })
  );
} ```
````