# How to pass optional parameter to a function in react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to set an optional parameter to a function using javascript. i have a function defined like below,

```
const function1 = () => {
    setValue(!open);
};
```

i call it like below in other function

```
const main_function = () => {
    function1();
}
```

now i want to pass an optional parameter to function1 to accept an optional parameter that sets it to true or false instead of toggling based on previous value.

how can i fix this. could someone help me with this thanks.

Comment: `function1 = (optionalParam = false) => {}`

Comment: `setValue(!open);` don't do this. Use functional update as your new state depends on the previous state. `setValue(prevState => !prevState)`.

Comment: @VLAZ: so how do i  call function1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Comment: `function1()` or `function1(true)` or `function1(false)`

Answer (score 5):

I hope this helps someone, you can just set the value to null like code below:

```
 const function1 = ({arg1=null, arg2= false, arg3, ...}) => {
  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a default value like so:

```
function multiply(a, b = 1) {
  return a * b
}

multiply(5, 2)          // 10
multiply(5)             // 5
```

Example taken from
[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Answer (score 1):

we can't make function arguments optional in javascript directly. However, we can assign them a default value, in case no arguments is passed through. this is how you do it-

```
const abc = (arg1, arg2= 'default value') => {
//arg1 is required. however if arg2 is not passed in any case, the default value //will be used in place.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the if the argument is defined or not, like:

```js
const function1 = (arg) => {
  setValue(arg === undefined ? !open : arg);
};
```

Comment: What is your use-case?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you want something like this.

```
const function1 = (param) => {
    setValue(params ? true : false);
}
```

It will set `true` if `param` is available otherwise false.
Correct me if I'm wrong.