# How to set a default param without affecting others in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Coming from Python, I'm used to defining default params like this:

```
def someFunc(defarg1=0, defarg2=10, defarg3="Hello", defarg4=100):
```

Then I can use it like so:

```
someFunc(defarg3="Goodbye")
```

In Javascript, I understand you can do the same in the definition:

```
someFunc(defarg1=0, defarg2=10, defarg3="Hello", defarg4=100) {}
```

But when I want to call the function and only change, say, defarg3, I can't do that since each argument is converted to positional arguments and their names are ditched. So doing this in Javascript doesn't work:

```
someFunc(defarg3="Goodbye");
```

From what I understand, I need to pass every other argument before defarg3. And since I don't want to change the default args before it, I have to supply the same default value:

```
someFunc(0, 10, "Goodbye");
```

Perhaps I'm missing something, but this seems incredibly redundant and prone to making mistakes. What if a function has a whole lot of default args and I just want to change one. There has to be a way instead of redundantly supplying the same default argument for previous args every time.

Comment: It's not a pretty solution, but you could pass `undefined` into the argument positions where you want to use the defaults

Comment: You are pretty much correct, there is no real way around this in JavaScript.

Comment: @GlenCarpenter, not true there is a solution, don't use traditional arguments, use an object `{}` instead. That allows for unlimited data to be passed.

Comment: @imvain2 While that would work as a workaround, I'm not sure if that's a solution for this specific question. What if you don't want to / are not able to change the function definition for which you're passing in the arguments?

Comment: @imvain2 that is an interesting workaround, wouldn't have thought of it!

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can author the parameters then use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with default properties. This enables you pass an object with only the parameters that you need to pass without having to respect the position of the argument.

```js
function example({ a = true, b = false, c = 1 } = {}) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
}

example({ b: true });
example({ a: false });
example({ c: 0, a: false, b: true });
example();
```

Comment: Didn't think to use objects. This really seems like the best workaround that at least satisfies what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What I prefer to do is pass an "object" instead of using arguments. Then you can access a parameter within the function like `args.parameter`.

You can also have a default set of data then just "merge" both together.

```js
function test(p){
  d = {
    "default" : 3
  }
  
  args = Object.assign(d, p);
  
  console.log(args);
}

test({
  "test" : 1
});

test({
  "test2" : 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a positional parameter list, use an object,  [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and default values:

```js
function someFunc({ defarg1=1, defarg2=2, defarg3=3, defarg4=4 }) {
  console.log(defarg1, defarg2, defarg3, defarg4)
}

someFunc({ defarg2: 'bananas' }) // 1 bananas 3 4
someFunc({ defarg2: null })      // 1 null 3 4
someFunc({ defarg2: undefined }) // 1 2 3 4
someFunc({})                     // 1 2 3 4
someFunc()                       // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defarg1' of undefined
someFunc(undefined)              // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defarg1' of undefined
someFunc(null)                   // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defarg1' of null
```

Note:

- default values are used when the property is not specified, or its value is `undefined`. This will suit most use cases.
- an object must be supplied as an argument for this pattern to work

**If you want to permit the user to supply nothing at all to the function** then you must supply a default value for the outer object parameter too.

Note that if `null` is supplied as an argument, the default value is not triggered.

```js
function someFunc({ defarg1=1, defarg2=2, defarg3=3, defarg4=4 } = {}) {
  console.log(defarg1, defarg2, defarg3, defarg4)
}

someFunc({ defarg2: 'bananas' }) // 1 bananas 3 4
someFunc({ defarg2: null })      // 1 null 3 4
someFunc({ defarg2: undefined }) // 1 2 3 4
someFunc({})                     // 1 2 3 4
someFunc()                       // 1 2 3 4
someFunc(undefined)              // 1 2 3 4
someFunc(null)                   // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defarg1' of null
```

Finally, if you invoke the function with [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), you can avoid using object destructuring and make use of the fact that [arrays support elision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas):

```js
function someFunc(defarg1=1, defarg2=2, defarg3=3, defarg4=4) {
  console.log(defarg1, defarg2, defarg3, defarg4)
}
someFunc.apply(null, [,'bananas']) // 1 bananas 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, see rest parameter javascript

```
function somefunc(...args) {
 // args is an Array
 console.log(args);
}
```