# How to call function with sometimes less argument

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function such as:

```
var func = function(arg1, arg2) {
    callAnotherFunc(arg1, arg2);
}
```

as you can see, when someone needs to call `func`, it needs to pass 2 args. sometimes, arg2 can be null.

Sometimes, `arg2` will be null. Is there some shortcut which allows me to do this ?

```
var func = function(arg1, arg2) {
    callAnotherFunc(arg1, arg2 || nothing);
}
```

So if arg2 is null, it shouldn't pass another argument to `callAnotherFunc` at all. I am looking for some shortcut and not `if/else`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Comment: You could also use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Comment: Would a simple `if` not be faster and more clear in the end? Watching this from readability and maintainability perspectives, I would just stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

[How To Use ES6 Arguments And Parameters](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/07/how-to-use-arguments-and-parameters-in-ecmascript-6/)

```js
var func = (...args) => {
    callAnotherFunc(...args);
}

var callAnotherFunc = (...args) =>{
  console.log(...args)
}

func(1);

func(1,2);

func(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Looks nice. Yet changes the signature of `func` an does not really regard `So if arg2 is null, it shouldn't pass another argument to callAnotherFunc at all.`

Comment: you can filter the args when you call the `callAnotherFunc(...args.filter(arg => arg !== null))`

Comment: You can, but you are not doing it. Also this would omit the first argument as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could forward all [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) which are not `null` by using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```js
var callAnotherFunc = function(){
  console.log(arguments)
};

var func = function(arg1, arg2){
    //So if arg2 is null, it shouldn't pass another argument to callAnotherFunc at all. 
    callAnotherFunc.call(
      null,
      Array.from(arguments).filter(function(item, index){
        return index == 0 || item !== null
      })
    )
};

func(1, 2);
func(1, null); //REM: Does not pass second argument
func(null, null); //REM: Does not pass second argument
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want to this, maybe your intentions are beyond my understanding. You can just use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters)

```
var func = function(arg1, arg2 = null) {
    callAnotherFunc(arg1, arg2);
}

var callAnotherFunc = function(arg1, arg2 = null){
    // console.log(arg1);
    // console.log(arg2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn't. Just use `if` / `else`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var func = function(...args) {
    // args will be an array of all the arguments
    if (args[1] == null) args.splice(1, 1);
    callAnotherFunc.apply(this, args);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Luca for this suggestion. I will try to improve the answer quality and explanation in future.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var func1 = function(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1, arg2);
}

var func = function(arg1, arg2) {
    arg2 && func1(arg1, arg2);
}

func(1, 2);

func(1); // not consoled
```