# An argument with default value precedes non-default argument in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript it's possible to define a function like this:

```
function func(a = 10, b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

How does one call this function by only specifying the value for `b`?

Comment: `func(undefined,1)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function), also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd only be possible by explicitly passing `undefined`, and by also providing a default for the second argument.

```js
function func(a = 10, b) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log(func(undefined, 5));
```

But this is quite weird - it's very confusing. I'd highly recommend not doing this at all - either put the arguments with default values at the end, or in an object.

```js
function func({ a = 10, b }) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log(func({ b: 5 }));
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually came across this syntax in Redux using TypeScript as providing a default argument for the reducer state was the only way to make `createStore` work. It felt strange, so I was wondering why that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with currying the first parameter:

`bind` saves the function with the arguments supplied, so when one calls it, it calls it with the arguments applied. The first argument is what to bind `this`  to, so the second argument will bind to `a`:

```js
function func(a, b) { 
    return a + b;
}

newFunc = func.bind(null, 10)
newFunc(2)
12
```