# Change javascript code based on input value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a program that hides your history by what you are searching

```
function bruh() {
  var win = window.open();
  win.document.body.style.margin = '0';
  win.document.body.style.height = '100vh';
  var f = win.document.createElement("iframe");
  window.focus();
  var url = "URLINPUT";
  if (!url) return;
  f.style.width = "100%";
  f.style.height = "100%";
  f.style.border = 'none';
  f.style.margin = '0';
  win.document.body.appendChild(f);
  f.src = url
}
```

so they input a url. and the URLINPUT changes to what they are trying to search

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I can not figure out how to have it so when they input a website using <input>, it will change the code to the javascript, so that instead of it saying URLINPUT, it will say (for example: youtube.com) if they were to input youtube.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parameters in your function.

```js
function bruh(url) {
  var win = window.open();
  win.document.body.style.margin = '0';
  win.document.body.style.height = '100vh';
  var f = win.document.createElement("iframe");
  window.focus();
  // url is already declared in function
  if (!url) return;
  f.style.width = "100%";
  f.style.height = "100%";
  f.style.border = 'none';
  f.style.margin = '0';
  win.document.body.appendChild(f);
  f.src = url
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Please type a URL!" onchange="bruh(this.value);" value="Please type a URL!">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will execute the function when the input is changed with the value of the text input.

[More information is on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

Answer (score 0):

Make `url` a function parameter.

```
function bruh(url) {
  if (!url) return;
  var win = window.open();
  win.document.body.style.margin = '0';
  win.document.body.style.height = '100vh';
  var f = win.document.createElement("iframe");
  f.style.width = "100%";
  f.style.height = "100%";
  f.style.border = 'none';
  f.style.margin = '0';
  win.document.body.appendChild(f);
  f.src = url
}
```

Then your search field can be something like:

```
<input id="search" onchange="bruh(this.value)">
```