# Object equals another object syntax

Tags: javascript

There is a function in the testing section in the redux docs and I'm trying to figure out what this syntax means.

```
export function renderWithProviders(
  ui,
  {
    preloadedState = {},
    // Automatically create a store instance if no store was passed in
    store = setupStore(preloadedState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  }
  return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) }
}
```

It seems like there's an object being passed as an argument and then it's assigned to nothing? Trying to figure out what the {...properties} = {} syntax means in the function declaration.

Thank you!

Comment: Check the second paragraph on the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function). *In ES6, you can simulate default named parameters via restructuring*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems like there's an object being passed as an argument and then it's assigned to nothing?

I assume you're referring to the `= {}` at the end of (and at the start of):

```
 {
    preloadedState = {},
    // Automatically create a store instance if no store was passed in
    store = setupStore(preloadedState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
```

That's default argument value syntax.  To show a simpler example, if I had a `paintCar` function, and I wanted to default my car to an empty object if none is provided, I could do:

```
function paintCar(paintColor, car = {}) {
    car.color = paintColor;
    return car;
}

// this works, even though I didn't provide a car:
const redCar = paintCar('red'); // { color: 'red' }
// ... because JS defaults that argument to "{}"
```

For any argument, to any function, you can add a `= something` to make it default to that something.  The only requirement is that all the defaults have to come last, so you can't do (say):

```
function fake(foo=1, bar){
```

(or technically you can, but when you do `fake(someBar)` it will get counted as the `foo` argument, not the `bar` argument)