# What is the difference between these two children uses in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm confused on these different uses of children and why they work. Can anyone explain? Is children a default parameter for react native functions?

```
const Component = ({
  children = <Text>Insert Icon</Text>,
}) => {
  return ( {children} );
};

const Component = ({
  {children},
}) => {
  return ( {children} );
};
```

Not a problem, just want an explanation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is children a default parameter for react native functions?

Yes. You can set default value for parameters in function:

```
const multiply = (a, b = 1) => {
  return a * b;
}

console.log(multiply(5, 2));
// Expected output: 10

console.log(multiply(5));
// Expected output: 5
```

More info: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Answer (score 0):

when you set

```
({
  children = <Text>Insert Icon</Text>,
})
```

it's mean if children = null, hence children = `<Text>Insert Icon</Text>`