# javascript: expecting true or false but getting number

Tags: javascript

I have something like the following:

```
var val = "string";
var testVal = val && val.length;
```

I would expect `testVal` to be either `true` or `false` but it is the length of the string.  Not sure why this is?

Comment: At first I was going to downvote, but then I realized you were getting a number instead of true, false and not the other way around.

Comment: @Juhana Is there a better more generic duplicate, because that one is specific to logical operators returning objects and wouldn't turn up in a future search of someone with this problem.

Comment: @Goose You can look for one from the linked questions of that question. The person who asked the question chose a not-so-good answer, but the [answer with the most votes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8569966/502381) explains the issue in the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logical `&&` operator doesn't perform a type casting. The expression it forms is just evaluated to the left-hand operand if this operand is falsy, otherwise to the right-hand operand.

You have to explicitly convert to boolean:

```
var testVal = !!(val && val.length);
```