# An unusual curious JS statement with && in the middle

Tags: javascript

I am making sense of an old project that was thrown on me on job. Stumbled upon the following piece (given these two variables were declared somewhere before):

```
someVar = 234 && !anotherVar;
```

Is it just a mistake or some fancy ninja move?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: Do you understand `if (234 && !anotherVar)`? Then what don't you understand about this?

Comment: @deceze it's not the same

Comment: @Maxx How's it different?

Comment: @deceze `if (234 && !anotherVar)` executes code by condition and `234 && !anotherVar` returns value. in this example `someVar` will be equal `!anotherVar`, because `Boolean(234)` is `true`

Comment: @Maxx Obviously so. Obviously this is not an `if` statement. I'm asking the OP whether they understand the `234 && !anotherVar` *in* `if (234 && !anotherVar)`…

Comment: I understand it, I don't understand why did he put it here? Does the statement after && affect the assignment in the left part? Why did he put it here, if the left part will be evaluated anyway?

Comment: We don't know why a particular developer writes a particular piece of code. If the left hand side is indeed `234`, hardcoded, then it's indeed pretty darn pointless and the whole thing could be abbreviated to `someVar = !anotherVar`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't logical operators (&& and ||) always return a boolean result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417969/why-dont-logical-operators-and-always-return-a-boolean-result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

&& is logical AND

> It expects two arguments and returns:
>
> First term that evaluates to false (is false-y).
>
> Last term **otherwise** (if no term evaluates to false)

Here are some examples:

```
0 && false          0 (both are false-y, but 0 is the first) 
true && > false     false (second one is false-y) 
true && true        true> (both are true-y) 
true && 20          20 (both are true-y)
```

This definition completely conforms to the definition of logical and from the field of mathematics.

Read More @ [Good Explanation of & vs &&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310109/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Comment: I know perfectly what i&& is. I'll refine the question.

Comment: @shal look at the highlighted text. Im not saying you dont know what && is, its rather a more extensive explanation of what && does in certain scenarios. In this case, "Last term otherwise" is happening.

Comment: Ok, I just realized how stupid this question is, but I can't delete it. What a shame... Thank you for your patience!